# How do I create then use long Windows paths from Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, long-filenames

I have part of a build process that creates a hideously long paths in Windows. It's not my fault. It's several directories deep, and none of the directory names are abnormally long; they're just long and numerous enough to make it over `MAX_PATH` (260 chars). I'm not using anything other than ASCII in these names.

The big problem is that the blow-up happens deep in the guts of [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build) during the `dist` target, although I figure the build system doesn't matter because they'd make the same directories.

Creating one of these overly-long directories with `File::Path` fails:

```
 use File::Path qw( make_path );

 make_path( 'C:\\.....' ); # fails if path is over 260 chars
```

Similarly, constructing each directory level by hand fails once the absolute path would go over `MAX_PATH`.

This isn't new, isn't Perl's fault, and Microsoft documents it in [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maximum_path_length). Their fix suggests adding the `\\?\` in front of any path to access the Unicode filename API. However, that doesn't seem to be the full fix for a Perl script because it still fails:

```
 use File::Path qw( make_path );

 make_path( '\\\\?\\C:\\.....' );  # still fails if path is over MAX_PATH, works otherwise
```

This might be because `make_path` pulls apart its argument and then goes through the directories one level at a time, so `\\?\` only applies to the top-level, which is within `MAX_PATH`.

I dug up a [bug report to ActiveState](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26342) that suggests there's something else I need to fix up to get to the Unicode filenames, and Jan Dubois gives a bit more details in [Re: "long" filenames on Windows 2K/XP](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-users@listserv.activestate.com/msg22349.html), although I'm not sure it applies (and is extremely old). [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) mentions that this use to be the job of the `-C` switch, but apparently that part was abandoned. The perl RT queue has a more recent bug [60888: Win32: support full unicode in filenames (use Wide-system calls)](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=60888).

Miyagawa [notes some Unicode filename issues](http://bulknews.typepad.com/blog/2008/12/pathclass-and-unicode-filename-woes.html) and [Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32API-File) without specifically mentioning long paths. However, the [Win32API::File CPAN Forum entry](http://www.cpanforum.com/threads/10658) seems to indicate only fear, which leads to anger, which leads to hate, and so on. There's an example in the [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/) post [How to stat a file with a Unicode (UTF16-LE) filename in Windows?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=741797). It seems the `Win32::CreateDirectory` is the answer, and I'll try that the next time I get next to a Windows machine.

Then, supposing I can create the long path path. Now I have to teach Module::Build, and maybe other things, to handle it. That might be immediately easy with monkeypatches if `Win32::GetANSIPathName()` does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows has two separate system call for each function that needs to deal with strings, an "A" call using the ANSI aka Active Code Page as the encoding (e.g. cp1252) and a "W" call using UTF-16le. Perl uses "A" calls, while `\\?\` only works with "W" calls.

You can use Win32::API to access the "W" calls as shown in the script below, but [Win32::LongPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::LongPath) not only uses the "W" calls, but automatically adds `\\?\`!

Example of using Win32::API to call `CreateDirectoryW` to use a long path (`\\?\`-prefixed path):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;
use Encode qw( encode );
use Symbol;

use Win32;

use Win32API::File qw(
    CreateFileW OsFHandleOpen
    FILE_GENERIC_READ FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
    OPEN_EXISTING CREATE_ALWAYS FILE_SHARE_READ
);

use Win32::API;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);

Win32::API->Import(
    Kernel32 => qq{BOOL CreateDirectoryW(LPWSTR lpPathNameW, VOID *p)}
);

my %modes = (
    '<' => {
        access => FILE_GENERIC_READ,
        create => OPEN_EXISTING,
        mode   => 'r',
    },
    '>' => {
        access => FILE_GENERIC_WRITE,
        create => CREATE_ALWAYS,
        mode   => 'w',
    },
    # and the rest ...
);

use ex::override open => sub(*;$@) {
    $_[0] = gensym;

    my %mode = %{ $modes{$_[1]} };

    my $os_fh = CreateFileW(
        encode('UCS-2le', "$_[2]\0"),
        $mode{access},
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        [],
        $mode{create},
        0,
        [],
    ) or do {$! = $^E; return };

    OsFHandleOpen($_[0], $os_fh, $mode{mode}) or return;
    return 1;
};

my $path = '\\\\?\\' . Win32::GetLongPathName($ENV{TEMP});
my @comps = ('0123456789') x 30;

my $dir = mk_long_dir($path, \@comps);
my $file = 'test.txt';
my $str = "This is a test\n";

write_test_file($dir, $file, $str);

$str eq read_test_file($dir, $file) or die "Read failure\n";

sub write_test_file {
    my ($dir, $file, $str) = @_,

    my $path = catfile $dir, $file;

    open my $fh, '>', $path
        or croak "Cannot open '$path':$!";

    print $fh $str or die "Cannot print: $!";
    close $fh or die "Cannot close: $!";
    return;
}

sub read_test_file {
    my ($dir, $file) = @_,

    my $path = catfile $dir, $file;

    open my $fh, '<', $path
        or croak "Cannot open '$path': $!";

    my $contents = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh or die "Cannot close: $!";
    return $contents;
}

sub mk_long_dir {
    my ($path, $comps) = @_;

    for my $comp ( @$comps ) {
        $path = catfile $path, $comp;
        my $ucs_path = encode('UCS-2le', "$path\0");
        CreateDirectoryW($ucs_path, undef)
            or croak "Failed to create directory: '$path': $^E";
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Comment: Try appending \0 at the end of path

Comment: ...before converting it to UTF-16LE

Comment: Okay, this is half of an answer I think. I also need the path in a form that the rest of the program can use without the acrobatics. I'm not going to be able to patch most of the CPAN toolchain for this. :)

Comment: I'm not in front of my Windows machine until tomorrow. That Win32::GetANSIPathName() looks promising. It sounds like it can give me a path name that everything else can use without knowing the details.

Comment: @Sinan - If you're going that route, what about junction points? I used your code above (the mk_long_dir part) to create a long path that was inaccessible from Explorer. I traversed as far as possible along the path and created a junction point at C:\foo to that spot. This let me traverse all the way to the end where I set another junction point at C:\bar. In Explorer, I was then able to create C:\bar\test.txt. As for Perl, I was unable to access test.txt via the long path, but was able to open, read and write to C:\bar\test.txt with no problems.

Comment: @bish Of course, that works, but this needs to happen sort of transparently during the build process.

Comment: I just highly modified this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Following code actually creates quite deep (more than 260 characters long) directory structure. At least on my machine:

```
use Win32::API;

$cd = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'CreateDirectoryW', 'PP', 'N');

$dir = '\\\\?\\c:\\!experiments';

$res = 1;

do
{
    print 'path length: ' . length($dir) . "\n";
    $dirname = pack('S*', unpack('C*', "$dir\0"));  #dirty way to produce UTF-16LE string

    $res = $cd->Call($dirname, 0);
    print "$res\n";

    $dir .= '\\abcde';

} while ( $res );
```

Answer (score 2):

*I understand this is not a solution to your specific problem. However, there are a lot of scenarios where being able to map a very long path to a drive-letter would allow one to sidestep the issue and would therefore be useful in dealing with very long path names without having to wade through a whole lot of Windows specific code and docs.*

Despite all the effort I put into figuring out how to do this, I am going to recommend somehow using `SUBST`. [Win32::FileOp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::FileOp) provides `Subst` and `Unsubst`. You can then map the top level working directory to an unused drive letter (which you can find by using `Substed`). I would start checking with `Z` and working backwards.

Or, you can shell out, invoke `subst` utility with no parameters to get a list of current substitutions, choose one that is not there.

None of this is entirely safe as substitutions could change during the build process.

Comment: Much cleaner than trying to use a Windows shortcut.

Comment: This wouldn't be high on my list of things to try. It has to work across processes. Also, I need to do this up to 100 times, so I foresee other disasters.

Comment: The IT folks have reasonably shot down this one. This is a shared build machine with a lot going on, so I don't get to create new virtual drives.

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment but posting code in comments is hardly useful.

UNC paths do not work either:

```
C:\> net share
perlbuild    e:\home\src
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Slurp;
use Path::Class;

my $top = dir('//Computer/perlbuild');
my @comps = ('0123456789') x 30;

my $path = dir($top, @comps);

make_path $path, { verbose => 1 };

my $file = file($path, 'test.txt');

write_file "$file" => 'This is a test';

print read_file "$file";
```

Result:

```
mkdir \\Computer\perlbuild\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456
789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789
\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\0123456789\01
23456789\0123456789: No such file or directory; The filename or extension is too
 long at C:\Temp\k.pl line 15
```

Answer (score -1):

I had three thoughts, all of them kind of hacks:

1. Start with some short directory names (C:\data_directory\a\b\c\d\4\5\6\...) and then rename the directories (starting with the deepest directory first of course).
2. Create Windows shortcut to a moderately long path and create files and subdirectories from there? (Or install Cygwin and use symlinks?)
3. Create the desired files in a directory with a short name, zip/tar them, and unpack them to the directory with the longer name. Or create zip/tar files "by hand" and unpack them in the desired location.

Comment: (1) is not going to work unless you are using the right Win32 API (in which case you would use it in the first place), (2) Cygwin's utilities could not navigate to or remove the subdirectories I created using the scripts in my post, (3) might work, depending on what you are using to unzip.

Comment: Although some of those might be fantastically wicked, remember that I have to get this to work from within Module::Build. I need to create the directory and return a path so that the rest of the process is none the wiser. Creating the path is only half the problem.

Comment: Windows shortcuts are nothing like symlinks. They are more akin to `*.desktop` files. The main difference is that shortcuts are binary files. Only recently have you been able to have symlinks, and that requires admin level authority.