# How do I create a Unicode directory on Windows using Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, directory

I struggle to create directory names containing **Unicode**. I am on Windows XP and Perl Camelbox 5.10.0.

Up until now I used to `use File::Path qw ( make_path )` to create directories - which worked fine until the first cyrillic directory appeared.

For files `Win32API::File qw ( CreateFileW )` works fine if the file name is UTF-16LE encoded. Is there something similar for directories? Or maybe a parameter to tell `CreateFileW` to create the Unicode path if it doesn't exist?

Thanks,
Nele

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721807/how-do-i-create-then-use-long-windows-paths-from-perl

Comment: @Sinan: If I read it correctly, your example below is a small part of the answer you gave in the beforementioned thread. I read the thread briefly when it came up on SO in November but didn't remember it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Win32.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32) provides an interface to `CreateDirectory` and friends:

> `Win32::CreateDirectory(DIRECTORY)`
>
> Creates the `DIRECTORY` and returns a true value on success. Check `$^E` on failure for extended error information.
>
> DIRECTORY may contain Unicode characters outside the system codepage. Once the directory has been created you can use `Win32::GetANSIPathName()` to get a name that can be passed to system calls and external programs.

#### Previous answer:

**Note:** Keeping this here for the record because you were trying to use `CreateDirectoryW` directly in your program.

To do this by hand, import [`CreateDirectoryW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28VS.85%29.aspx) using [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::API):

```
Win32::API->Import(
    Kernel32 => qq{BOOL CreateDirectoryW(LPWSTR lpPathNameW, VOID *p)}
);
```

You need to encode the `$path` for `CreateDirectoryW`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use utf8;

use Encode qw( encode );
use Win32::API;

Win32::API->Import(
    Kernel32 => qq{BOOL CreateDirectoryW(LPWSTR lpPathNameW, VOID *p)}
);

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDERR, ':utf8';

my $dir_name = 'Волгогра́д';

my $ucs_path = encode('UCS-2le', "$dir_name\0");
CreateDirectoryW($ucs_path, undef)
    or die "Failed to create directory: '$dir_name': $^E";
```

```
E:\> dir
2010/02/02  01:05 PM              волгогра́д
2010/02/02  01:04 PM              москва
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll use Win32::CreateDirectory. I am new to the Unicode universe and find it quite complicated - maybe this is only true on Windows using Perl - I don't know.

Comment: The name returned by Win32::GetANSIPathName() doesn't seem to work with external commands. Does it perhaps need to be translated to the system codepage or something?

Answer (score 0):

Just updating this question for 2018.

Unbelievably, ActivePerl 5.24 *still* does not support simply passing Unicode paths to `open()`/`mkdir()`, and by extension `File::Path::mkpath()`, because the underlying Perl code still calls the 20th-century ASCII version of Windows `CreateFile()`.   Insanity!  How could this not have been a higher priority than the myriad obscure Perl changes made in the intervening 10 years?!

This is true *even* if you 'use utf8;' or a myriad other incantations.

So, even today, we still have to have special-case code for Windows for this most basic function (creating/accessing Unicode filenames).

Fortunately, the `Win32::Unicode` module has a nice, easy-to-use `Win32::Unicode::Dir::mkpathW()` function which does exactly what you want and works for Unicode (as well as great `copyW()` and `moveW()` functions).

Unfortunately, this module hasn't passed its installation tests since Perl 5.16 and ActiveState dropped it from its handy ppm repository ( https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Win32-Unicode/ ).

Fortunately, there is a way to get it working, as the 3 tests that fail (relating to "print") are not used for file/directory creation:

Step 1: `ppm install dmake`

Step 2: `ppm install MinGW`

Step 3: `perl -MCPAN -e shell` then `force install Win32::Unicode`

Step 1 and 2 are required even if you already have Microsoft Visual Studio installed on your computer; apparently Perl is now built with MinGW and modules must be as well.

Phew.