# How do I copy a file with a UTF-8 filename to another UTF-8 filename in Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl, utf-8, filenames

For example, given an empty file `テスト.txt`, how would I make a copy called `テスト.txt.copy`?

My first crack at it managed to access the file and create the new filename, but the copy generated `ãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆ.txt.copy`.

Here was my first crack at it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use English '-no_match_vars';
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;

use File::Copy;
use Win32;

my (
    $output_relfilepath,
   ) = process_command_line();

open my $fh, '>', $output_relfilepath or die $!;
binmode $fh, ':utf8';
foreach my $short_basename ( glob( '*.txt') ) {

  # skip the output basename if it's in the glob
  if ( $short_basename eq $output_relfilepath ) {
    next;
  }

  my $long_basename = Win32::GetLongPathName( $short_basename );
  my $new_basename  = $long_basename . '.copy';

  print {$fh} sprintf(
                      "short_basename = (%s)\n" .
                      " long_basename = (%s)\n" .
                      "  new_basename = (%s)\n",
                      $short_basename,
                      $long_basename,
                      $new_basename,
                     );
  copy( $short_basename, $new_basename );
}

printf(
       "\n%s done! (%d seconds elapsed)\n",
       basename( $0 ),
       time() - $BASETIME,
      );

# === subroutines ===

sub process_command_line {

  # default arguments
  my %args
    = (
       output_relfilepath => 'output.txt',
      );

  GetOptions(
             'help'                 => sub { print usage(); exit },
             'output_relfilepath=s' => \$args{output_relfilepath},
            );

  return (
          $args{output_relfilepath},
         );
}

sub usage {
  my $script_name = basename $0;

  my $usage = <<END_USAGE;
======================================================================

Test script to copy files with a UTF-8 filenames to files with
different UTF-8 filenames.  This example tries to make copies of all
.txt files with versions that end in .txt.copy.

  usage: ${script_name} (<options>)

options:

  -output_relfilepath <s>   set the output relative file path to <s>.
                            this file contains the short, long, and
                            new basenames.
                            (default: 'output.txt')

----------------------------------------------------------------------

examples:

  ${script_name}

======================================================================
END_USAGE

  return $usage;
}
```

Here are the contents of `output.txt` after execution:

```
short_basename = (BD9A~1.TXT)
 long_basename = (テスト.txt)
  new_basename = (テスト.txt.copy)
```

I've tried replacing [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)'s copy command with a system call:

```
my $cmd = "copy \"${short_basename}\" \"${new_basename}\"";
print `$cmd`;
```

and with Win32::CopyFile:

```
Win32::CopyFile( $short_basename, $new_basename, 'true' );
```

Unfortunately, I get the same result in both cases (`ãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆ.txt.copy`).  For the system call, the print shows `1 file(s) copied.` as expected.

Notes:

- I'm running Perl 5.10.0 via [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) on Windows 7 Professional
- I use the [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-0.39/Win32.pm) module to access long filenames
- The glob returns short filenames, which I have to use to access the file
- テスト = test (tesuto) in [katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana)
- I've read [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: What's the default encoding of your Windows? EUC-JP? Shift_JIS?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184726/how-do-i-create-a-unicode-directory-on-windows-using-perl

Comment: Mike: From general reading and using binmode ':utf8' I think my default encoding is utf-8, but I'm not 100% sure.
Sinan: Thanks for the link!

Comment: @vleeshue: Read the post Sinan pointed you to - I have managed to read/write files/directories using Unicode characters in their names on Windows by using his approach.

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible with the [CopyFileW](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API::File#CopyFileW) function from [Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API::File), which should be included with Strawberry.  I've never messed with Unicode filenames myself, so I'm not sure of the details.  You might need to use [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) to manually convert the filename to UTF-16LE (`encode('UTF16-LE', $filename)`).

Comment: That looks good. `CopyFileW` is certainly the underlying system call you'd need to use to do this; annoying it's not part of the `Win32` module.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the long filename using `Win32`, which gives you a UTF-8-encoded string.

However, you're then *setting* the long filename using plain `copy`, which uses the C stdlib IO functions. The stdlib functions use the default filesystem encoding.

On modern Linuxes that's usually UTF-8, but on Windows it (sadly) never is, because the system default code page cannot be set to UTF-8. So you'll get your UTF-8 string interpreted as a code page 1252 string on a Western European Windows install, as has happened here. (On a Japanese machine it'd get interpreted as code page 932 — like Shift-JIS — which would come out something like `繝�せ繝�`.)

I've not done this in Perl, but I'd suspect the `Win32::CopyFile` function would be more likely to be able to handle the kind of Unicode paths returned elsewhere in the `Win32` module.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I also tried both a standard windows copy (system call) and Win32::CopyFile to no avail (updated the question post with new findings).  I'm just (naively?) surprised at how difficult this is :(

Comment: Oh dear. If even the `Win32` interface won't accept Unicode filenames you may be pretty much scuppered. Yes, I'm afraid the combination of native-Unicode Windows and byte-string C stdlib is very uncomfortable thanks to Windows's refusal to standardise on UTF-8 for the encoding. It's not possible to handle Unicode filenames from a stdlib-only interface like Perl's core uses. :-( It was impossible on Python too, until special support was added to use the native Windows interfaces. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Encode::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Encode-Locale-1.03/lib/Encode/Locale.pm):

```
use Encode::Locale;
use Encode;
use File::Copy;

copy( encode(locale_fs => $short_basename),
      encode(locale_fs => $new_basename) ) || die $!;
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully duplicated your problem on my Windows machine (Win XP Simplified Chinese version) and my conclusion is that the problem is caused by the font. Choose a Truetype font rather than Raster fonts and see if everything is okay.

My experiment is this:

1. I first changed the code page of my Windows Console from the default 936 (GBK) to 65001 (UTF-8).
   by typing C:>chcp 65001
2. I wrote a scrip that contains the code: $a= "テスト"; print $a; and saved it as UTF-8.
3. I ran the script from the Console and found "テスト" became "ãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆ", which is exactly the same sympton you described in your question.
4. I changed the Console Font from Raster Fonts to Lucida Console, the console screen gave me this: "テストストトト", which is still not quite right but I assume it is getting closer to the core of the problem.

So althought I'm not 100% sure but the problem is probably caused by the font.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Unicode

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @kebabs = (
  "\x{45B}\x{435}\x{432}\x{430}\x{43F}.txt",               ## ћевап.txt
  "ra\x{17E}nji\x{107}.txt",                               ## ražnjić.txt
  "\x{107}evap.txt",                                       ## ćevap.txt
  "\x{43A}\x{435}\x{431}\x{430}\x{43F}\x{447}\x{435}.txt", ## кебапче.txt
  "kebab.txt",
);

{
    use Win32::Unicode qw/ -native /;
    printW "I \x{2665} Perl"; # unicode console out
    mkpathW 'meat';
    chdirW 'meat';
    for my $kebab ( @kebabs ){
        printW "kebabing the $kebab\n";
        open my($fh), '>:raw', $kebab or dieW Fudge($kebab);
        print $fh $kebab              or dieW Fudge($kebab);
        close $fh                     or dieW Fudge($kebab);
    }
}

sub Fudge {
    use Errno();
    join qq/\n/,
      "Error @_",
      map { "  $_" } int( $! ) . q/ / . $!,
      int( $^E ) . q/ / . $^E,
      grep( { $!{$_} } keys %! ),
      q/ /;
}
```