# Using Perl, is there a difference between Win32API::File::MoveFile and CORE::rename on MSWin32?

Tags: perl, winapi, file-rename, strawberry-perl

I see that [Win32API::File](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32API%3a%3aFile) supports `MoveFile()`. However, I'm not sure how `CORE::rename()` is implemented in such a fashion that it should matter. Could someone juxtapose the difference -- specifically for the Win32 Environment -- between

- `CORE::rename()`
- `File::Copy::move()`
- and, `Win32API::File::MoveFile()`

Answer (score 2):

`rename` is implemented in a [broken fashion since forever](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perltodo.html#Unicode-in-Filenames); `move` too, since [it uses `rename`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.16.0/lib/File/Copy.pm#L375).

[Win32::Unicode::File](http://p3rl.org/Win32::Unicode::File) exposes `MoveFileW` from `windows.h` as `moveW`, and apparently handles encoding in a sane fashion, whereas Win32API::File leaves that to the user AFAICS from existing example code.

Related: [How do I copy a file with a UTF-8 filename to another UTF-8 filename in Perl on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304319/how-do-i-copy-a-file-with-a-utf-8-filename-to-another-utf-8-filename-in-perl-on)

Comment: so if you don't have UTF-8 in the filename does it make a different if you just use CORE::rename()?

Comment: Yeah, what's the chance of that? Unicode of course never occurs in file names, so we programmers can be as care-free as [rainbow farting unicorns](http://forgifs.com/gallery/d/201297-1/Unicorn-farts.gif).

Comment: Well.. In this specific case I'm moving `/store/{sha1}.{ext}` to `/bak/{sha1}.{ext}` in a qty of about 10 million, so don't assume that I don't know my own workload. There is 0 chance of Unicode being in the file name.