# What is the universal way to use file I/O API with unicode filenames?

Tags: perl, unicode, filesystems

In Windows there is a [common problem](http://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=60888): the filenames should be converted to local codepage, before they are passed to `open()`. Of course, there is a possibility to use [`Win32::API`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184726/how-do-i-create-a-unicode-directory-on-windows-using-perl) for that, but I don't want my script to be platform-dependent. At the moment I have to write something like:

```
open IN, "<", encode("cp1251", $filename) or die $!;
```

but is there any library, that hides these details? I think the local codepage can be automatically detected, so I just want to pass unicode filename and forget about the details. Why is it still not in the box?

Comment: Found relative post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721807/how-do-i-create-then-use-long-windows-paths-from-perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **used** to just work until 5.8.1, then Jarkko took it out, and broke the `-C` switch in an gratutious incompatible change on top. This makes Windows a second class citizen and annoys me until today, because any other dynamic language does not have this ridiculous defect. Perhaps now is a good time that we could hear a justification for this change for the worse.

Anyway, you want [`PerlIO::fse`](http://p3rl.org/PerlIO::fse), but it's not a perfect solution, as you will soon discover on your own.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks a lot. Maybe you can give a link to `-C` (enables given Unicode features) switch discussion? What was the reason to break compatibility?

Comment: I've got your point: the behaviour of `-C` has been dramatically changed and now does not control the wide character API setting, so it cannot be used as a solution for a problem anymore (I've found the complete list of current options here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*). Do you happen to know any discussion thread (say: critics) about new policy for `-C` switch?

Comment: http://markmail.org/message/ijklg7cnr6xv6bgu http://markmail.org/message/fjiiyvbuck75v5sa