# Convert JSON string of unicode characters to dict Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, unicode

I am trying to count the number of Unicode characters in the JSON data. I am using requests to get the data from the feed.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://venmo.com/api/v5/public?since=1438578858&until=1438578958')'
j_data = r.text
```

Now, I need to convert the `j_data` into a dictionary to get the `message` items alone. If I just use `json.loads(j_data)`, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character`.

Therefore, I am encoding the `j_data` and then trying to convert to dict using `loads`. I am getting this error

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

How to approach this problem?

Code:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://venmo.com/api/v5/public?since=1438578858&until=1438578958')

j_data = r.text

encoded = j_data.encode()

b = json.loads(encoded)
print(b)
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `json` attribute of the response object (`r`) instead of decoding it yourself‽

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in Python 2.7.6

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('https://venmo.com/api/v5/public?since=1438578858&until=1438578958')
contentJ = json.loads(req.content)
```

and I get a dict named contentJ

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you try to encode something, that does not need to be encoded. Stripping of the line with the encoding and all works fine in Python3.4.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://venmo.com/api/v5/public?since=1438578858&until=1438578958')

j_data = r.text

b = json.loads(j_data)
print(type(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get json, use `r.json()`:

```
import requests # $ pip install requests

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

Your error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character.` is unrelated to the json parsing. Most likely it happens when you are trying to print Unicode to Windows console. Configure the console font that can display the desired characters and install `win-unicode-console` package:

```
T:\> py -mpip install win-unicode-console
T:\> py -mrun your_script_that_prints_unicode.py
```

See [What's the deal with Python 3.4, Unicode, different languages and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30539882/4279)