# Cannot print unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm working with dbf database and Armenian letters, the DBF encoding was unknown so I've created a letter map to decode revived string. Now I have a valid Unicode string, but I cannot print it out because of this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to

What I have tried so far:

```
print u'%s' %str ## Returns mentioned error
print repr(str) ## Returns string in this form u'\u054c\u0561\u0586\u0561\u0575\u0565\u056c
```

How to fix it?

Comment: unrelated: `str` is a builtin name, don't replace it. `u'%s' % s` is unnecessary if `s` is a Unicode string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do the following:

```
newStr = str.encode("utf-8")
print newStr
```

P.S. Had this problem with another language, was able to view letters when wrote them into a file.

Comment: It looks like this answer should produce mojibake. The error mentions `charmap` (probably something like cp437), not utf-8. Do not hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have changed encoding settings in my IDE. I use PyCharm.

Go to: "File -> Settings... -> Editor -> File Encodings" and change everything to needed charset. 
I hope it will help to someone.
[image: Where to change File Encodings]

Answer (score -1):

To print a valid Unicode string, use `print(unicode_string)`.

The error suggests that you are on Windows. To print Unicode on Windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551552/4279) -- it is for Python 3.4 but it should work for Python 2.7 with minor modifications.