# Cant' get correct representation for some Italian words

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, encoding, io, nltk

I need to normalize text from Italian wiki using python3 and nltk and I've got one problem. Most of the words are OK, but some words are mapped incorrect, to be more exact - some symbols.

For example:

> 'fruibilit\xe3', 'n\xe2\xba', 'citt\xe3'

I'm sure that the problem is in symbols like à, è.

Code:

```
# coding: utf8
import os

from nltk import corpus, word_tokenize, ConditionalFreqDist


it_sw_plus = corpus.stopwords.words('italian') + ['doc', 'https']
#it_folder_names = ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF']
it_path = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\1\\projects\\i')
it_corpora = []

def normalize(raw_text):
    tokens = word_tokenize(raw_text)
    norm_tokens = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token not in it_sw_plus and token.isalpha():
            token = token.lower().encode('utf8')
            norm_tokens.append(token)
    return norm_tokens

for folder_name in it_path:
    path_to_files = 'C:\\Users\\1\\projects\\i\\%s' % (folder_name)
    files_list = os.listdir(path_to_files)
    for file_name in files_list:
        file_path = path_to_files + '\\' + file_name
        text_file = open(file_path)
        raw_text = text_file.read().decode('utf8')
        norm_tokens = normalize(raw_text)
        it_corpora.append(norm_tokens)
    print(it_corpora)
```

How can I resolve this problem?
I'm running on Win7(rus).

When I try this code:

```
import io

with open('C:\\Users\\1\\projects\\i\\AA\\wiki_00', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print (line)
```

In PowerShell:

```
    <doc id="2" url="https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=2" title="Armonium">

Armonium



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (line)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>
```

In Python command line:

```
<doc id="2" url="https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=2" title="Armonium">

Armonium



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\1\projects\i.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (line)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position
3: character maps to <undefined>
```

When I try the request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position
90: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Could you post the original file online? Otherwise it's hard to know what is the true encoding of the file.

Comment: https://github.com/GiteItAwayNow/TrueTry/blob/master/it

Comment: `open()` with `encoding=` parameter can only be used in `python3`! In python2 use `import io; io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: Try installing this: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/win_unicode_console/win_unicode_console-0.4.zip and then correct your code to use `io.open` for python2 or stick with only python3 and see whether you read and print the text properly.

Comment: alvas, sorry, my mistake.
But when I use python3 in PowerShell it raises the error like In the Python command line.
I've tried the code in Python IDLE and it works correct.

Comment: Powershell has strange default encoding for stdout. In powershell, what is your output for `import sys; print (sys.stdout.encoding)`? Did you see something like `cp850`?

Comment: If you see `cp850`, then please install the https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/win_unicode_console/win_unicode_console-0.4.zip , it should work better than hacking the environment variables, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined

Comment: Ok. Thank you, alvas.

Comment: Did the `win-unicode-console` work?

Comment: alvas, thank you! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding when reading the file if you know the encoding, in `python2`

```
import io
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print line # line should be encoded as latin-1
```

But in your case, the file you've posted isn't a `latin1` file but a `utf8` file, in `python3`:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiteItAwayNow/TrueTry/master/it'
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>> data = response.read()
>>> text = data.decode('utf8')
>>> print (text) # this prints the file perfectly.
```

To read a 'utf8' file in `python2`:

```
import io
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print (line) # line should be encoded as utf8
```

To read a 'utf8' file, in `python3`:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print (line) # line should be encoded as utf8
```

As a good practice, when dealing with text data, try to use unicode and python3 whenever possible. Do take a look at

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type
- [What's the deal with Python 3.4, Unicode, different languages and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539882/whats-the-deal-with-python-3-4-unicode-different-languages-and-windows)
- [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

Additionally, if you haven't install this module for printing utf8 on windows console, you should try it:

```
pip install win-unicode-console
```

Or download this: https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/win_unicode_console/win_unicode_console-0.4.zip and then `python setup.py install`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think that the encoding is latin1? Especially when it looks like a wikipedia file, utf8 would have been the first guess.

Comment: Or I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position
90: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Can you post your full code in the question. I'm not exactly sure what caused it the unicode mapping to fail. Did you try with the `request` url too? Did that work fine?

Comment: Did the error happen in the printing or at the for loop? If it's at the printing, then it's most probably because you can't print utf8 properly on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I tried with the request and I got the UnicodeEncodeError.

alvas, what do you mean about full code? The full module in the question.

Comment: Please post the edited one with `utf8` and how you're reading the file.