# Can not access socket.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want simulate client - server node.

Here is my server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){ 
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){

             /*  if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404 1");

                }
                */

                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                   // response.write("data terbaca 2"); 
                    response.write(data, "utf8");

            }); 
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
            response.write('hello world2 + ' + __dirname + ' ' + path);

            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404 3");
            break;
    }
    response.end(); 
}); 

server.listen(8000);
```

and here is my client html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Ini Socket html lohhh</body>
</html>
```

My directory strucure is in
D:/cobaa
 1. server.js
 2. socket.html

I node the server, and access the localhost:8000/socket.html
and get

> hello world2 + D:\cobaa /socket.html

can anybody get me the solution,please?
Big thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Answer (score 1):

The catch here is you are finishing the response before you actually write the file contents. The `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, so the writing of the file contents is deferred until the read completes, so it reaches `response.end()` first and executes it.

The response should only be sent after file has been read. So put all your response handling inside the callback

```
        fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){

            /*  if (error){
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404 1");
                }
            */
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.write('hello world2 + ' + __dirname + ' ' + path);
                response.end();
        });
```

Comment: should those response.write calls and respond.end be async chained with callbacks, or does respond internally push those to a list to be iterated on end? I ask because usually I see only a single response.send call, which perhaps provides all of this.

Comment: @Paul They don't need callbacks. response being a stream `response.write`s are peformed in the order they are given (they use Eventemitters, write events are queued). `response.end` should be executed only once, which sends the response. Doing res.send(x) is equivalent to first res.write(x) then res.end()

Comment: wow, sorry I came from blocking and syncronous technology. With nodeJS asynchronous feature, still bias to me. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I have moved the response.end. I get blank every time I access the socket.html. When I check the page source, it still black too.