# How to overwrite constructor property from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, xmldataprovider, jasmine-node

I am new in JavaScript programming and I have got no idea even how to ask Google, so i will describe in detail what I would like to achieve.

I am using node.js and xml2js module to create DataProvider class for jasmine, that parse simple XML file:

```
<Tests>
    <Test name="test1">
        <values>2,4,6</values>
        <expectations>1,2,3</expectations>
    </Test>
    <Test name="test2">
        <values>8,10,12</values>
        <expectations>4,5,6</expectations>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

I would like DataProvider constructor to parse XML immediately and have result visible in `this.testData`.
The script is:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js'),
    util = require('util');

var DataProvider = function(dataPath) {
    this.dataPath = dataPath;
    this.testData;

    fs.readFile(this.dataPath, function(err, data) {
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            //console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
            this.testData = result;
        });
    });
};
```

I am using it like follows:

```
var dp = new DataProvider("C:\\data2.xml");
console.log(dp.testData);
```

When I am running the script `>node script.js` I am receiving `undefined`.
When I uncomment `console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));` I am receiving

```
undefined
{ Tests: 
   { Test: 
      [ { '$': { name: 'test1' },
          values: [ '2,4,6' ],
          expectations: [ '1,2,3' ] },
        { '$': { name: 'test2' },
          values: [ '8,10,12' ],
          expectations: [ '4,5,6' ] } ] } }
```

so generally it works, but how to assign `result` to `this.testData`?

Is this connected with scope of `this.testData`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get data from fs.readFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile)

Comment: According to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile) you can use `readFileSync` instead of `readFile`. However, this goes against the asyncness of node.js - you might want to consider changing your interface to something with an async `init` method instead of bundling everything in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript utilises async paradigm a lot, so when you read file for example - function you provide as callback will be executed in own scope. `this` is related to scope, so you will lose it. After you are trying to reference `this.testData` will actually not reference DataProvider object, but scope of anonymous function you've provided to parseString.

So there are few ways to overcome, and easiest here would be persist `this` in variable in upper scope, so you can reference it, call it for example `self`, some devs prefer `that`.

```
var DataProvider = function(dataPath) {
    this.dataPath = dataPath;
    this.testData;

    var self = this;

    fs.readFile(this.dataPath, function(err, data) {
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            //console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
            self.testData = result;
        });
    });
};
```

Or by using `.bind`, but dissadvantage here is that it has to be used twice (as you have two scopes to 'travel' through:

```
var DataProvider = function(dataPath) {
    this.dataPath = dataPath;
    this.testData;

    fs.readFile(this.dataPath, function(err, data) {
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            //console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
            this.testData = result;
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Thank you.
What about `.bnid(this)` will it work somehow? Is it more elegant?

Comment: What are the other ways to overcome?

Comment: There are few, `.bind` is one of them as well, updated the answer.