# How to read file to variable in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

i'm pretty new into NodeJs. And i am trying to read a file into a variable.
Here is my code.

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path"),
    util = require("util");
        var content;
        console.log(content);
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname,"helpers","test.txt"), 'utf8',function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            content = util.format(data,"test","test","test");
        });
        console.log(content);
```

But every time i run the script i get
`undefined` and `undefined`

What am i missing? Help please!

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous (which is why you use a callback). Either do everything from the callback or use `var content = fs.readFileSync("filename")`

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: It returns a Buffer. How to convert Buffer to String?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from fs.readFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Comment: @user2540315 add 'utf8' after the filepath to make it not read buffer text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the comments under your question, node is asynchronous - meaning that your function has not completed execution when your second `console.log` function is called.

If you move the log statement inside the the callback after reading the file, you should see the contents outputted:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    path = require("path"),
    util = require("util");
var content;
console.log(content);
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "helpers", "test.txt"), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    content = util.format(data, "test", "test", "test");
    console.log(content);
});
```

Even though this will solve your immediately problem, without an understanding of the async nature of node, you're going to encounter a lot of issues.

[This similar stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10058879/808532) goes into more details of what other alternatives are available.

Answer (score 9):

The following code snippet uses ReadStream. It reads your data in separated chunks, if your data file is small it will read the data in a single chunk. However this is a asynchronous task. So if you want to perform any task with your data, you need to include them within the ReadStream portion.

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/readMe.txt', 'utf8');
/* include the file directory and file name instead of <__dirname + '/readMe.txt'> */

var content;

readStream.on('data', function(chunk){
    content = chunk;
    performTask();
    
});

function performTask(){

    console.log(content);

}
```

There is also another easy way by using synchronous task. As this is a synchronous task, you do not need to worry about its executions. The program will only move to the next line after execution of the current line unlike the asynchronous task. 
A more clear and detailed answer is provided in the following link:

[Get data from fs.readFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile/10058879#10058879)

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var content = fs.readFileSync('readMe.txt','utf8');

/* include your file name instead of <'readMe.txt'> and make sure the file is in the same directory. */
```

Answer (score 6):

or easily as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const doAsync = require('doasync');

doAsync(fs).readFile('./file.txt')
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

One very simple way:

```
var json = require("./file.json");
console.log(JSON.stringify(json 4, true));
```