# Not able to read the file using fs nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, fs

I am new bee in learning node js. I am trying to read a file from the same directory and then to print its contents using file system's (fs) readFile method. I see that the program is not entering into this method when I run it. I tried putting console.log() in readFile method and I see it is not printing anything inside this method.

I am not knowing exactly what is happening and why it is skipping this method.

here is the canvas-util.js file that I am running using mocha

```
"use strict";

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');


module.exports.getEmailVariables = function(name, next) {
    name = "running?";
    var err = "";    
    var data1;

    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.txt');

    fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data){
        console.log(name);
        if (!err){
        console.log('received data: ' + data);
        data1 = data
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    next(err, data1);
};
```

My test.js contains

```
var canvasUtil = require("../utils/canvas-util");
var assert = require("assert");

describe('Mindrill', function () {
    this.timeout(30000);

    it('getEmailVariables should return Email variables', function (done) {
        var name="";
        canvasUtil.getEmailVariables(name, function(err, results) {

            assert.notEqual(null, results);                       
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

And sample.txt contains just "hi".

checking to see if I am getting the string in file to the variable 'data1' so as to pass the test. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` is async. Put your `next(err, data1);` inside the `fs.readFile()` callback.

Comment: almost looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963858/how-to-read-file-to-variable-in-nodejs, within the time I change I got your answer.. Asynchronous is really a big think to take concern while programming in node js. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `fs.readFile();` why not use `fs.readFilesync();` ? You could try the same parameters.