# Why is fs.readFile returning a buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile) already. That is, I don't believe my problem lies in a misunderstanding of async.

Here is the relevant part of my module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var q = require('q');
var u = require('../utils/json');

var indexFile = './data/index.json';

function getIndex() {
    var def = q.defer(),
        promise = def.promise,
        obj;

    fs.readFile(indexFile, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            def.reject(err);
        }
        console.log('data', data);

        def.resolve(obj);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

When I log 'data', I'm getting a buffer (below), rather than the JSON content of that file.

```
<Buffer 5b 7b 22 68 65 6c 6c 6f 22 3a 22 77 6f 72 6c 64 22 7d 5d>
```

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: as an aside, don't throw `err` if you want to reject your deferred with it.

Comment: @Andbdrew good point. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: And the reason the API defaults to a buffer instead of a string is that buffers are the only safe way of reading binary data. But you can convert a buffer to a string even after reading it by either calling `.toString()` directly of appending forcing it into a string context: `'' + buffer`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per the [Node.js API docs for 'fs' module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback), if the `encoding` option isn't passed, the `read` functions will return a buffer.

If you pass a value for encoding, it will return a string with that encoding:

`fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', 'utf-8', callback)`

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, fs module requires the encoding option as second parameter.

Also, if you are sure that your file consists utf-8 string, you can use;

```
fs.readFile(indexFile, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return def.reject(err);
    }

    console.log('data', data.toString());

    def.resolve(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... You need to include encoding

```
fs.readFile(indexFile,'utf8', function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    //Do something with data
    console.log(data);
});
```