# node.js does not recognise the url in the unfluff module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Any help will be appreciated.

I need to extract data from websites and found that node-unfluff does the job (see https://github.com/ageitgey/node-unfluff). There is two ways to call this module.

First, from command line which works!
Second, from node js which doesn't work.

```
extractor = require('unfluff');
data = extractor('test.html');
console.log(data);
```

Output : `{"title":"","lang":null,"tags":[],"image":null,"videos":[],"text":""}`

The data returns an empty json object. It appears like it cannot read the test.html.

It seems like it doesn't recognise test.html. The example says, "my html data", is there a way to get html data ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`unfluff`](https://github.com/ageitgey/node-unfluff):

> extractor(html, language)
>
> html: The html you want to parse
>
> language (optional): The document's two-letter language code. This
>   will be auto-detected as best as possible, but there might be cases
>   where you want to override it.

You are passing a filename, and it expects the actual HTML of the file to be passed in.

If you are doing this in a scripting context, I'd recommend doing

```
data = extractor(fs.readFileSync('test.html'));
```

however if you are doing this in the context of a server or some time when blocking will be an issue, you should do:

```
fs.readFile('test.html', function(err, html){
    var data = extractor(html);
    console.log(data);
));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. How do you pass in the actual HTML ? When I read the docs, it says, html, I thought it meant, the name of the file . Any help to get me started will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jessi You can use the [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) method of the `fs` module for reading the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been working on it since yesterday night.