# node.js make code wait until the fs.readFile is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I got a problem in node.js file system.
here is my code. 
my function always return a empty string.
I'm wondering is there anyway to make my function stop execute until readFile method is completed.

```
var fs = require('fs');
function myfun(filePath){
  var str = '';
  fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    str = data;
  });
  return str; //here, the variable str always return '' because the function doesn't wait for the readFile method complete.
}
```

---

add explanation

Actually I'm doing something like this:
the function myfun is used for replace str
you can see my code:

```
function fillContent(content) {
  var rex = /\<include.*?filename\s*=\s*"(.+?)"\/>/g;
  var replaced = fileStr.replace(rex, function (match, p1) {
    var filePath = p1
    var fileContent = '';
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      fileContent = data;
    });
    return fileContent;
  });
  return replaced;// here, the return value is used for replacement
}
```

I need a return value in the replace function, so this is why I didn't use a callback function

Comment: @GopinathShiva puting `return str;` inside the callback will not do any good. OP you're looking for `fs.readFileSync()`.

Comment: for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Comment: If you really need to use it with `.replace()`, you should use `fs.readFileSync()`.

Comment: thank robertklep, I'm wondering whether I used fs in a replace function is a good way

Answer (score 14):

If you need to do it synchronously then you should use fs.readFileSync() (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) instead.

```
var fs = require('fs');
function myfun(filePath){
  return fs.readFileSync(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass a callback to `myfun` function as below in order to get back data from the function when file reading is over:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function myfun(filePath, cb){
  var str = '';
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    cb(data);
  });
}

// call it like this 
myfun('some_path', function(data) { /* use returned data here */} );
```

You need to invest some time into better understanding of asynchronous nature of JavaScript.

The problem with your code is that `return str` is outside of the `readFile` callback, which means `return str` executes earlier than the `readFile` callback gets called to set `str` to a meaningful value.

Comment: This is the way to go with nodejs - although I would probably add the utf8 encoding parameter because it looks like the OP is expecting a string to be returned.