# How to run a github javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I'm looking for a node js code to read and write in one text file. On guthub I have found a promising script from Arahnoid:

https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725#file-read-write-file-js

If I try to execute it, I get the error "File is not defined (line 3 ... new file(txt...). I guess, I have to install a npm package. But I don't know which one.

Can anybody give my a hint how I get to run this javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js

Comment: thanks, mplungjan. I already have found this thread too. But unfortunately I have to less experience to understand and use that. Therefore I was looking for a read to use script.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about node.js environment and not in browser right? In node look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile to read a file and @mplungjan paster how to write a file

Answer (score 2):

> I guess, I have to install a npm package

You don't. If you needed to install an npm package then the code would include a `require` statement trying to load it.

> Can anybody give my a hint how I get to run this javascript?

It is completely undocumented code found lying around in the Internet.  Stop trying.

If you want to read a file using NodeJS then look at NodeJS' documentation. A [basic search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nodejs%20read%20file) will turn up the built in [file system api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
        throw err;
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

(And there's a matching `writeFile` method to go with that).

Answer (score -1):

It requires Nodejs Enviroment to run the file.

Resource: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm

Comment: The code linked from the question won't work in NodeJS.