# JS | Get a price from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

So I am trying to match `market_hash_name` from my JSON file and then get value `price`, but I'm having problem with the JSON file seems so. I'm trying to loop through it, but I'm getting error that `length` is undefined. on `data.prices.length`

Here is my function

```
function fixItems(items){
    var fixeditems = [];
    fs.readFile('prices.json', 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        for(var i in items.itemsToReceive){
            for(var k = 0; k < data.prices.length; k++){
                if(items.itemsToReceive[i].market_hash_name == data.prices[k].market_hash_name){
                    console.log(data.prices[k].price);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return fixeditems;
}
```

Calling the function

```
console.log(fixItems(JSON.parse('{"partner":{"universe":1,"type":1,"instance":1,"accountid":212532673},"id":"1929552531","message":"Your deposit for CSGOParmud has been sent. Your secret code:q3mer","state":7,"itemsToGive":[],"itemsToReceive":[{"appid":730,"contextid":"2","assetid":"9422864987","classid":"927007517","instanceid":"143865972","amount":1,"missing":false,"icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA","icon_url_large":"","icon_drag_url":"","name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","name_color":"D2D2D2","background_color":"","type":"Base Grade Key","tradable":true,"marketable":true,"commodity":true,"market_tradable_restriction":7,"fraudwarnings":[],"descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"This keyonly opens Chroma 2 Cases","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":" ","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":"","color":"00a000","app_data":{"limited":"1"}}],"owner_descriptions":[],"tags":[{"internal_name":"CSGO_Tool_WeaponCase_KeyTag","name":"Key","category":"Type","category_name":"Type"},{"internal_name":"normal","name":"Normal","category":"Quality","category_name":"Category"},{"internal_name":"Rarity_Common","name":"Base Grade","category":"Rarity","color":"b0c3d9","category_name":"Quality"}],"id":"9422864987","actions":[],"owner_actions":[],"market_marketable_restriction":0},{"appid":730,"contextid":"2","assetid":"9411034993","classid":"927007517","instanceid":"143865972","amount":1,"missing":false,"icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA","icon_url_large":"","icon_drag_url":"","name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","name_color":"D2D2D2","background_color":"","type":"Base Grade Key","tradable":true,"marketable":true,"commodity":true,"market_tradable_restriction":7,"fraudwarnings":[],"descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"This key only opens Chroma 2 Cases","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":" ","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":"","color":"00a000","app_data":{"limited":"1"}}],"owner_descriptions":[],"tags":[{"internal_name":"CSGO_Tool_WeaponCase_KeyTag","name":"Key","category":"Type","category_name":"Type"},{"internal_name":"normal","name":"Normal","category":"Quality","category_name":"Category"},{"internal_name":"Rarity_Common","name":"Base Grade","category":"Rarity","color":"b0c3d9","category_name":"Quality"}],"id":"9411034993","actions":[],"owner_actions":[],"market_marketable_restriction":0},{"appid":730,"contextid":"2","assetid":"9411034945","classid":"927007517","instanceid":"143865972","amount":1,"missing":false,"icon_url":"-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA","icon_url_large":"","icon_drag_url":"","name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","market_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key","name_color":"D2D2D2","background_color":"","type":"Base Grade Key","tradable":true,"marketable":true,"commodity":true,"market_tradable_restriction":7,"fraudwarnings":[],"descriptions":[{"type":"html","value":"This key only opens Chroma 2 Cases","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":" ","app_data":""},{"type":"html","value":"","color":"00a000","app_data":{"limited":"1"}}],"owner_descriptions":[],"tags":[{"internal_name":"CSGO_Tool_WeaponCase_KeyTag","name":"Key","category":"Type","category_name":"Type"},{"internal_name":"normal","name":"Normal","category":"Quality","category_name":"Category"},{"internal_name":"Rarity_Common","name":"Base Grade","category":"Rarity","color":"b0c3d9","category_name":"Quality"}],"id":"9411034945","actions":[],"owner_actions":[],"market_marketable_restriction":0}],"isOurOffer":true,"created":"2017-03-11T17:16:47.000Z","updated":"2017-03-11T17:17:03.000Z","expires":"2017-03-25T17:16:47.000Z","tradeID":null,"fromRealTimeTrade":false,"confirmationMethod":0,"escrowEnds":null}')));
```

Comment: JSON needs to be parsed into a JavaScript value first. Also `fs.readFile` is asynchronous so the function will always return **before** the array is populated.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the answer, could you please make me a example in piece of code?

Comment: You already know how to parse JSON.

Comment: It tells me undefined if I'm trying to do ex: var something = JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Okay, seems like I'm just stupid. Could you please post it as answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from fs.readFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile)

Comment: @FelixKling If I'm trying to push into the array `fixeditems` it comes out as empty. Why?