# Read from localhost in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to load async from same server running my React, but this doesn't work ( if I set path from remote it works), error is `Invalid URI` :

```
request.get('statefulsetv.yaml', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(error);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = yaml.load(body);
                // console.log(data);
                containers = data.spec.template.spec.containers;
                self.setState({ containers_state: containers });



                // Continue with your processing here.
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to read a file, you should do it using `fs`.  There's an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Comment: what is your `request` object ?

Comment: I suppose every file you want to read needs to have the full URL. You need to prepend your `statefulsetv.yaml` with `http://localhost:port`, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/statefulsetv.yaml`