# Pass HTML File content to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, loopbackjs

I have this template.html that I am going to use as an email template, on loopback/nodejs. in PHP I able to do the following:

```
ob_start();
include template.php;
$template = ob_get_clean();
```

Is there anyway possible I can do this with javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from fs.readFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile)

Comment: Hi, I found the answer to the question you link! so thank you! but I would like to maintain this post, simply because it has a better title/description than the other one. It can serve as an alternative. Because I most people who are new to javascript would not even think of `fs.readFile` as search keyword.

Comment: Great! "Closing" this question as duplicate will leave the question on the site but it will be marked as a duplicate which adds a header near the title linking to the other question(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile), thanks to [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt)

```
const fs = require('fs');
var template = fs.readFileSync('template/emailtemplate.php','utf8');
console.log(template);
```