# looping through an json array list

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

the following array list I need to get all the price one by one. 
this returns the full json object `console.log('File data:', jsonString);` but the for loop never seems to get called , it never enters it.  I need to loop through a json file but its in different folder the json file is under menu folder called list.json menu-> projectName\menu\list.json the file looks like this
The data:

```
[
  {
    "code": "ZC",
    "price": "1"
  },
  {
    "code": "ZS",
    "price": "3"
  },
  {
    "code": "VC",
    "price": "4"
  },
...]
```

JS:

```
const jsonList = fs.readFile("../menu/list.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("File read failed:", err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("File data:", jsonString);
  console.log("File data:", jsonString.url);
  for (var key in jsonString) {
    if (jsonString.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log("===>", jsonString[key].price);
    }
    return jsonString;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to convert your jsonList using JSON.parse method something like jsonList = JSON.parse(jsonList) just before your for loop

Comment: Not sure of the issue with your code but a simpler approach might be jsonList.forEach { item => console.log("==>" + item.price }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix the issue you are facing, one is to have your code run inside the callback:

```
const jsonList = fs.readFile("../menu/list.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("File read failed:", err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("File data:", jsonString);
  for (var key in JSON.parse(jsonString)) {
    if (jsonList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log("===>", jsonList[key].price); // This is never called
    }
  }
});
```

or by using [sync function to read file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options):

```
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync("../menu/list.json", "utf8");
console.log("File data:", jsonString);
const jsonList = JSON.parse(jsonString);
for (var key in jsonList) {
  if (jsonList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log("===>", jsonList[key].price); // This is never called
  }
}
```

Comment: the sync function returns undefined, I dont get it

Comment: console.log("File data:", jsonString); this returns the json object but the .price is undefined :(

Comment: both are undefined

Comment: @benji_r,  can you post the file `list.json` structure?

Comment: I updated my answer, just missed using the parsed JSON.

Comment: that was it thank you so much const jsonList = JSON.parse(jsonString);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213134/discussion-between-benji-r-and-mamoun-othman).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop in the callback as it is async and so jsonList is not the object you expect when you access it. See [Get data from fs.readFile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10058814/2568649)

Comment: this is giving me undefiend console.log('====> ', jsonList);

Comment: I think that makes sense based on async - what if you put console.log(jsonString) instead of return jsonString. Does that show it as you expect at that point

Comment: console.log('File data:', jsonString); this gives me the correct stuff, however moving the forloop into the fs .readfile returns undefined

Comment: for (var key in jsonString) {
        console.log('byeeeee')
        if (jsonString.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log('===>',jsonString[key].price);
    
         }
    }

Comment: Possibly doesn't explain undefined but as Syam mentioned you need JSON.parse(jsonString) so instead of return jsonString, JSON.parse(jsonString).forEach { item => console.log(item.price) }

Comment: Can you copy your updated code into a comment and let us know what is undefined

Comment: Updating the code in the question is a really bad idea because now the answers that are posted make no sense. You should append an update to your question ie leave original as is, and then add a bit to say you updated code and it still doesn't work - here is the updated version .

Comment: const jsonList = JSON.parse(jsonString); that is what I needed . thank you somuch for your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213133/discussion-between-benji-r-and-chris).