# Javascript Array.push creating a nested array which I cannot access using the index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mern, array-push

I have looked at the following articles, which all go into depth about asynchronous calls return undefined.

[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

[Get data from fs.readFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile/10058879#10058879)

This doesn't answer my question, however. In my example, I am using `async`, and `await`, and `.then`. The async function IS returning something, and populating the array, however it is the format of the array, and the ability of dealing with the array that I am struggling with.

I am using the following code to populate an array with objects from my MongoDB database.

```
const initialClasses = [];

const getInitData = async () => {
  await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/classes/api/')
    .then(response => {
      initialClasses.push(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
  getInitData();
  console.log(initialClasses);
```

When I console.log initialClasses, however, I get the following array:

```
[]
0: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] // objects provided from the async call
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

When I try to access this array, using `console.log(initialClasses[0]);` i get undefined.

What have I done wrong in creating this array? Is there a better, cleaner way to do this which I have overlooked? Thanks.

Comment: The `initialClasses` updated only once you get a responce, but you console it immediately. ether console it inside the `.then(...)` function, or call the `getInitialData` synchroniusely, using the `await` keyword

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have console logged within the .then(...), and the array is correct. The problem, however, is that any variables that I set within the getInitData block is not within the scope of the rest of my application.

To call getInitData using await, I would need to call it in another async function, which itself would have its own scope, not allowing me to access the data outside the function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think I'd recommend revisiting [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
as your understanding of asynchronous behavior grows. I believe it's at the root of the problem here (hence why this feels like a duplicate to some members of the community).

Why you get `undefined` when you call `console.log(initialClasses[0])` will depend on when you call that and again we'd expect undefined if you call it too early and misunderstand how `async` works.

But instead of getting into those weeds, let's get to the root of your question: Is there a cleaner way? Yes! Probably the misunderstanding here comes from the way you've structured this. You can simplify it a lot and get the same functionality.

You can call the following inside of an async function

```js
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/classes/api/');
let initialClasses = response.data;
```

This would be the preferred way since whatever you are wanting to do with the response from that endpoint is fundamentally asynchronous. This way the response data won't be 'nested' either.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation and patient nature! Very appreciated, and just what we need in the community :D. I'm going to do more research into async, and will revisit the post when I understand it more. Again, thanks.