# Calling function always returns undefined, but console.log's correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 files, containing names. And I want to generate a random combination of names from both the files.
But when I call my function, it console.log() the name correctly, but stores undefined in the `couple` variable.

My current code looks like follows:

```
function getRandomLine(filename) {
  fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    data += "";
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    line = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
    console.log(line);
    return line;
  });
}

function generateRandomCouple(f1, f2) {
  male = getRandomLine(f1);
  female = getRandomLine(f2);
  return male + " & " + female;
}

couple = generateRandomCouple("./maleNames.txt", "./femaleNames.txt");
console.log(couple);
```

The output I get is:

```
undefined & undefined
Sam
Penny
```

Also, I am still very confused about when to use something.then().catch() vs async/await vs this callback style of code.
Is there a good way to think about when to use what?

Edit:
If I use `readFileSync`, I get the following on console:
`undefined & undefined`

Comment: You are returning line from a callback function to fs.readFile. You have to return data from getRandomLine and to do that read file in sync mode.

Comment: your function getRandomLine is async and the return is inside the readFile callback

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058814/get-data-from-fs-readfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting the `callback` functions to be executed at the time of calling a function `synchronously`.

Update your code similar to below

```js
async function getRandomLine(filename) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err); // Reject in case of error
      data += "";
      var lines = data.split("\n");
      line = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
      console.log(line);
      resolve(line); // Resolve if success
    });
  });
}

async function generateRandomCouple(f1, f2) {
  male = await getRandomLine(f1);
  female = await getRandomLine(f2);
  return male + " & " + female;
}

(async function() {
  couple = await generateRandomCouple("./maleNames.txt", "./femaleNames.txt");
  console.log(couple);
})();
```

Comment: the last 2 lines are outside any function. So await wont work. If I remove the await, couple = `Promise { <pending> }` . What should I do?

Comment: Yes... We can only use `await` inside an `async` function. It won't work outside of function.

Comment: so, what can I do?

Comment: You can use self invocation function. Updated my answer.

Comment: it is only storing the female name and not the male name :(

Comment: both the names are printing, but when I print the couple name, I get something like 
` & Stella`

Comment: It should work unless any typos. Or overriding of `male` name in any other place in your code. Try printing both name before `return` statement of `generateRandomCouple` function

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` runs asynchronously. `getRandomLine` returns undefined instantly. To make it work as inended, you might like to use `async-await`. Something like this:

```
async function getRandomLine(filename) {
 var x=  await fs.readFile(filename, 'binary');
  ....
 return new Buffer(x)
}
```

Comment: I tried this and x stores `undefined`

Comment: Still doesn't work.
returns undefined.