# Check if File is Compressed via Snappy

Tags: node.js, snappy

I'm trying to test if text is compressed via Snappy. I'm using the Node.JS https://github.com/kesla/node-snappy library.

credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168737/read-txt-file-using-node-js) for help on reading from a file.

```
$cat Decompress.js 
var snappy = require('snappy');
var fs     = require('fs');

var filename = './snappy_compressed_docs/snappy_compressed_file'

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;    
    console.log("done printing data. 'typeof data':", typeof data);

    console.log("snappy: ", snappy);

        snappy.isValidCompressed(data, function(e, result) {
        if(e) { console.log("error!", e); throw e; }
            console.log("snappy.isValidCompressed:", result);
    });
});
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
$node Decompress.js 
done printing data. 'typeof data': string
snappy:  { compress: [Function],
  isValidCompressed: [Function: isValidCompressed],
  uncompress: [Function] }
Assertion failed: (obj->HasIndexedPropertiesInExternalArrayData()),
 function Length, file ../src/node_buffer.cc, line 115.
Abort trap: 6
```

What's going on in the `Assertion failed...` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `isValidCompressed` expects a buffer, rather than a string.

Based on the assertion that failed, we can see that we're looking for weird properties in “external” array data, which means something somewhere is expecting something more raw than a JavaScript String. If we look at node-snappy's [`isValidCompressed` bindings](https://github.com/kesla/node-snappy/blob/master/src/binding.cc#L160-166), we see it's treating its input data as a `node::Buffer`. Since the `typeof data` is giving us `string`, we probably don't have the right type of data.

The solution here is to drop the `'utf8'` argument to `readFile`, which gives us the data as a raw buffer instead of trying to convert it into a string.