# Read text file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I don't know how this is possible new to programming.
I want to print the values which are present in abc.txt, but don't know how to do it using Node.js:

```
abc.txt
[
mainfodler/subfolder/pqr.pdf, PQR
mainfodler/subfolder2/xyz.doc, XYZ
mainfodler/subfolder/image1.jpg, Image
mainfodler/subfolder2/pqr.pdf, PQR
]
```

Expected output:

```
Array1:
[
mainfodler/subfolder/pqr.pdf
mainfodler/subfolder2/xyz.doc
mainfodler/subfolder/image1.jpg
mainfodler/subfolder2/pqr.pdf
]

Array2
[
PQR
XYZ
Image
PQR
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a text file using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168737/read-a-text-file-using-node-js)

Comment: I don't think so this answers the question. The expected o/p is segregated in two parts Array1 and Array2. It is just reading the whole file in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use readline from node.js. Here is the code you can use:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

async function readFile(filePath) {   
const myInterface = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream(filePath)});    
  const arrayLink = [],     
        arrayName = []; 

  for await (const line of myInterface) {
    let temp = line.split(",");
    arrayLink.push(temp[0]);     
    arrayName.push(temp[1]);     
  }
  console.log(arrayLink, arrayName);
}
readFile(filePath)
```

This Updated code will run the way you are expecting. Check this one.

Comment: Hello, I am writing this code in a function but when i am printing array by returning the array its showing me empty [ ] `function readFile(filePath) {
  const myInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
  });

  const arrayLink = [],
    arrayName = [];
  myInterface.on("line", function (line) {
    // console.log(line.split(","));

    let temp = line.split(",");
    arrayLink.push(temp[0]);
    arrayName.push(temp[1]);
    return [arrayLink, arrayName];
  });
  console.log(arrayLink, arrayName);
}` @apoorva

Comment: I have updated the image for the running code.

Comment: You need to understand, `console.log(arrayLink, arrayName);` will be called first and it will always print empty data.  and you can't return data like this `return [arrayLink, arrayName]; ` from an array instead you should wait for the result to read first and then get it.

Comment: its showing me console in myInterface.on() but not showing oustide what should i do and i wrote by mistakenly `return [ arrayLink, arrayName]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231075/discussion-between-apoorva-chikara-and-praveen).

Comment: Check the updated code. Try to run the same code and pass the file path.

Comment: Yes sorry for delay thank you and its working absolutely fine :) @apoorva

Comment: It's ok don't be sorry about it. We all are here to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example with the fs library. You can do something similar to the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('my-file.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Learn more with the docs [here](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/fs/)

Comment: I don't think so this answers the question. The expected o/p is segregated in two parts Array1 and Array2. It is just reading the whole file in one go.