# How to read a file line by line into an array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I need to be able to read a simple text file that contains a series of numbers for each line.

These numbers need to be read and stored somewhere in my code so I figure an array is the best way to go. Once the array has the values stored I can use it for further manipulation but I can't seem to actually read and push values into my array from each line in a text file.

What's the best way to do this? All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Cheers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831918/node-js-read-a-text-file-into-an-array-each-line-an-item-in-the-array

Comment: response.split("\n")

Answer (score 13):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');

var instream = fs.createReadStream('./test.txt');
var outstream = new stream;
var rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

var arr = [];

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  // process line here
  arr.push(line);
});

rl.on('close', function() {
  // do something on finish here
  console.log('arr', arr);
});
```

This approach also handles large text file.
https://coderwall.com/p/ohjerg/read-large-text-files-in-nodejs

Comment: Is there anyway to return the array instead of logging it ot the console (in the case where the above code was inside of a function)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js).

This is the solution proposed there:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
});
```

Has also been added to the [Node docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4609/files).