# indexOf in each line?

Tags: node.js, line, indexof

I'm just starting with node.js and i don't know how to figure out this thing.
I have a .txt file:

```
5+3=
5245+2=
76+0=
0-0+4=
```

All I want to do is log out positions of `+`.
I mean:

```
Line 1 position 2
Line 2 position 5
Line 3 position 3 
Line 4 position 4
```

I was trying with `indexOf` but it always showed me positions of `+` like the .txt file was in 1 line.

```
2,7,10,14
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a complete example? We need to see how you are reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could put each line of the txt file into an array item and iterate through that array to find the index of each item. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832105/4927000

Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var array = fs.readFileSync('[filename].txt').toString().split("\n");

for (i in array) {
    var index = i.indexOf('+');
    var line = i + 1;
    console.log('Line ' + line + ' position ' + index);
}
```