# How to read file and search for a string in it

Tags: javascript

**I will read a file and search for a string in it. and also which line number  to find string**

*here is code*

```js
fs.readFile('input.txt', "utf-8", function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data)
        }
```

*How to find string and line number*

*input.txt*

1. my
2. name
3. is
4. Arjun

*output:* 
line number, string
`4, Arjun`

Comment: You could check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831918/node-js-read-a-text-file-into-an-array-each-line-an-item-in-the-array. This will help you with the reading part. While you reading it line by line you could check if the current line contains the string you are looking for.

Comment: @Christos thanx for sharing the answer

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that can help you:

```
fs.readFile(FILE_LOCATION, function (err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;
 if(data.includes('search string')){
console.log(data)
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop:

```
const searchStr = 'aSearchTerm';
const lineArray = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split('\n');
for (const line of lineArray) {
    const lineNumber = line.split(/[\s.]+/)[0]; // regular expression (regex)
    const searchComponent = line.split(/[\s.]+/).slice(-1)[0]; // regex
    if (searchComponent === searchStr) {
        console.log(lineNumber.concat(', ', searchComponent))
        break;
    }
}
```

[Learn about JS array operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[Learn about JS string operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

[What are regular expressions?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)