# Execute function sequentially for each line of file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, wait, sequential

First of all, I've found similar questions but nothing quite matching my use case:

I have a file such as:

```
line1prop1 line1prop2 line1prop3
line2prop1 line2prop2 line2prop3
line3prop1 line3prop2 line3prop3
...
```

**I want to read the file line by line, execute a function for each line BUT wait for the function to finish before moving to the next line**

This is because for each line I have to extract the properties and make a request to Elasticsearch, to see if I have a matching document or not, but my cluster gets flooded with requests because I currently read everything asynchronously.

```
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  //EXECUTE FUNCTION HERE AND WAIT FOR IT TO FINISH
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the when you use `.on` listeners, you are listening to a event emitted

> The 'line' event is emitted whenever the input stream receives an
> end-of-line input (\n, \r, or \r\n). This usually occurs when the user
> presses Enter or Return.
>
> The listener function is called with a string containing the single
> line of received input.

Since it's a listener, you cannot control how event is being emitted.

line.pause() won't work here either because of the following

> Calling rl.pause() does not immediately pause other events (including
> 'line') from being emitted by the readline.Interface instance.

If you want to, you should probably read the entire the file in to a javascript array, and use `for loops` to go through each line.

[node.js: read a text file into an array. (Each line an item in the array.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831918/node-js-read-a-text-file-into-an-array-each-line-an-item-in-the-array)

Comment: The file has millions of lines, which makes loading it into memory impossible.