# Reading strings from a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am very new to javascript, and I want to read lines of strings into let's say an array, I used this:

```
  const fs = require('fs');

let words = [];

fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\words.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  words.push(data);
  console.log(words);
});
```

and it works, BUT, the output is formatted like this:

```
'wrong\r\n' +
    'year\r\n' +
    'yellow\r\n' +
    'yes\r\n' +
    'yesterday\r\n' +
    'you\r\n' +
    'young\r\n' +
    'Bernhard\r\n' +
    'Breytenbach\r\n' +
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: depends - what is wrong with it? you push a single value to an array, you'll get a single value out of an array

Comment: Seems like you want to read your file into an array line by line. So, does this answer your question? [node.js: read a text file into an array. (Each line an item in the array.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831918/node-js-read-a-text-file-into-an-array-each-line-an-item-in-the-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could do `words = data.split("\r\n")`. This will split your file into lines and saves it into the `words` array.

But keep in mind, that Unix like systems uses different line endings (`\n`) than Windows (`\r\n`).