# how to get total number of records rows in a csv file using node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, lazy-evaluation, fs

I have a csv file in local server.I am trying to get total number of rows in a csvfile at a time.But I am unable to do this.Please help.

Comment: look at this library https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

Comment: Do this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12453463/711902

Comment: it does not work properly.I want to get total no of rows in a csv file .In my case there is no "\r" or "\n".

Answer (score 1):

Used this snippet to calculate line count from [Jason Kim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453057/node-js-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file/12453463#12453463) and it worked like a charm.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function fileLineCount({ fileLocation }) {
  const { stdout } = await exec(`cat ${fileLocation} | wc -l`);
  return parseInt(stdout);
};

// Usage

async someFunction() {
  const lineCount = await fileLineCount({ fileLocation: 'some/file.json' });
}
```

P.S. This works for any type for file not just **csv**.

Answer (score 0):

Work with CSV through a library, as Plato suggested.

FWIW, to get the length of any text file,

```
var content;
// First I want to read the file
fs.readFile('./local.csv', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;
    processFile();          // Or put the next step in a function and invoke it
});

function processFile() {
    lines = content.split("\r");   // look up
    rowCount = lines.length;
}
```