# How to count the lines of a CSV file with Node-Express

Tags: node.js, csv, express

I need to count the lines of a CSV file. If the file is empty, I want to write the columns names as first line, then the info that I need to log.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: please update your question with an example

Answer (score 1):

```
var i;
var count = 0;
require('fs').createReadStream(process.argv[2])
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    for (i=0; i < chunk.length; ++i)
      if (chunk[i] == 10) count++;
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log(count);
  });
```

This is a duplicate of [Node.js: Count the number of lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453057/node-js-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file), please learn to google your problems first.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**
To count the lines of a CSV file you can use this.

```
fs.readFile('mfile.csv', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        let lines = null, data.toString().split('\n')
    }
})
```

**Detailed answer:** If the line count is 0, then you can write the header data such as column name.

```
fs.readFile('mfile.csv', function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        let lines = null, data.toString().split('\n')
        if(lines <= 0) {
           fs.writeFileSync('mfile.csv', 'cloumn name')
           console.log('added column name')
        }
        console.log('lines ' + lines)
    }
})
```