# How to detect oncomplete function when using readline module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, file

I am trying to read files 1 line at a time using this doc

https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

from the answer here
[Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js)

proposed by Dan.

The problem is, it doesn't specify how to call a function when the file is fully read from.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js/32599033#32599033), someone gives the answer to your question:

```
lineReader.on('close', callback);
```

Comment: Also is it possible to get the max line number? This is to show progress.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453057/node-js-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file

Comment: This is a way to get it by reading all the lines. I wanted a way to get it before even reading it.

Comment: So you want to know how many lines are in a file, without reading the file? That's clearly not possible.  If you want to show progress, you could get the *size* of the file at the start (that's a very fast operation) and keep track of the total number of characters you have read so far (counting the length of each line read).

Comment: For the current line string, is it each character=4bytes? And do I have to add 4bytes for the new line character?