# how to check how many lines of code in file using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to read line by line in file, but I have a doubt how to print count of line in file using `nodejs`.

**data.js**

```
console.log("123")

console.log("123")


console.log("123")



console.log("123")
```

**file.js**

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data.js')
});
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log('Line from file:', line);
});
```

I got this ouput

> Line from file: console.log("123")   Line from file:
>   Line from file: console.log("123")   Line from file:
>   Line from file:                       Line from file:
>   console.log("123")   Line from file:                     Line from
>   file:                     Line from file:                    Line from
>   file: console.log("123")

but I want how many lines of code in file using node js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453057/node-js-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file 
This can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i;
var count = 0;
require('fs').createReadStream(process.argv[2])
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    for (i=0; i < chunk.length; ++i)
      if (chunk[i] == 10) count++;
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log(count);
  });
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation about your answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('source', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    console.log(data.split('\n').length)
})
```

First of all import fs library, then, read file and get length by splitting data

Answer (score 2):

```
let count = 0;
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
   input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data.js')
});
lineReader.on('data', line => {
   for (i=0; i < line.length; ++i) if (line[i] == 10) count++;
})
.on('end', () => {
   console.log(count);
})
```

By looping the lines in file you count the number of lines this way. Also you can checkout this [link](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) for more details