# How to count total line numbers of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the total number of lines of an object file. How is this possible?

`let count = Object.keys(obj).length`
With this I can get the key wise value but it will not give the sub key like `"products"`

In this example total number of lines is `22`

```
{
"device-native-resolution": "1920x1080",
"discount": 
 {
   "amount": "52.00",
   "applicable": true
},
"email": "ddeech8e@gmail.com",
"order_id": 4248349409343,
"previous-vists": 3,
"products": 
[
   {
      "gift_card": false,
      "line_price": "0.00",
      "name": "Totebag",
      "price": "0.00",
      "product_id": 4567,
      "quantity": 1
    }
]
}
```

Comment: total number of keys or lines? be clear

Comment: Total number of lines

Comment: Lines are not significant in JSON. The example in the question would still be valid JSON if it had no \r or \n characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: Count the number of lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453057/node-js-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: You have 18 lines in the formatted object  - if you need to count the lines in a file that is then counting newlines in the string

Comment: @LavecartSolution Count the number of \n characters. It will be a fair approximation of what you're asking for, even though it is quite meaningless.

Comment: `const jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj,null,4); console.log(jsonString.split(/\n/).length)` gives 20 https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9oy3nug4/