# text processing - node.js vs perl performance

Tags: perl, node.js

How can I measure or 
is there a concrete proof,
which out of **node.js** and **perl** is better for **text parsing**

Comment: Answer: Whichever one you know better.

Comment: @SLaks - I know both and I would prefer node.js but i dont want to be biased

Comment: @TLP - Better would mean faster time. Time would take preference over space. Also, file IO would be done as the text is in persistent memory. The text files are present in various directories like n ary tree of depth 3 (max). I would like to push the data parsed into a database (noSQL or RDBMS)

Comment: @AbhisheshSharma That would depend on the type of parsing you do. You can probably optimise in a number of different ways as well. In the end, the only true test is trying it out for yourself.

Comment: Keep in mind that simple file operations are way more complex in Node.js than in Perl. Have a look at how many answers [Read a file one line at a time in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) has. And still, none of them really lets you stop reading after a certain number of lines and resume it on demand.

Answer (score 2):

you write a script in each, parsing some text and take the timestamp before - the timestamp after finishing the execution.