# Reading from files lazily in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, io, lazy-loading

I've tried this simple code using [node-lazy](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy):

```
var productStream = function (readstream) {
  return new Lazy(readstream)
    .lines.forEach(function (line) {
      console.log(count++);
      if (count > 10) {
        console.log("Should stop");
        readstream.pause();
      }
      return normalizeAttributes(JSON.parse(line.toString().slice(0, -1)));
    })
}

console.log(productStream(fs.createReadStream(datafile)).take(5));
```

Lazy does not stop after the tenth line, it sweeps through the whole file. Can anyone explain why? I've seen [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060062/182629), but I'm curious if there's a bug in the library or there's something else I need to do.

Comment: I believe forEach may be async

Comment: What do you mean? In my understanding, that's the whole point, is should only be called when the stream is emitting data events, hence the `pause`. I've logged and the pause is being called, so probably something else is happening because I don't explicitly call `resume` anywhere. I've written my own implementation of something similar with hand-rolled line parsing and a queue and it works just fine, but lazy's API is nicer.

Comment: I should have explained that better. What I meant was that the function passed in to forEach is executed for each line at the same time. It may not be sequential. So while count may be greater than 10 at some point it may come far after 10 lines have been read. My understanding on Lazy is a bit rough though so I may be WAY off the mark

Comment: If the stream is paused at any point the execution should stop, the function would have no data pumping events to be called upon. Or at least that's how I see it hence the question :). I tested on a large file, ~20000 lines. I also submitted a bug to the repo - https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/issues/39.