# Node.js Iterate CSV File for Requests, but Wait for Response Before Continuing the Iterations

Tags: node.js, csv, async.js

I have some code (somewhat simplified for this discussion) that is something like this

```
var inputFile='inputfile.csv';
var parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function (err, data) {
    async.eachSeries(data, function (line, callback) {
            SERVER.Request(line[0], line[1]);
            SERVER.on("RequestResponse", function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
            });
            callback();
    });
});

SERVER.start()

SERVER.on("ready", function() {
    fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser);
});
```

and what I am trying to do is run a CSV file through a command line node program that will iterate over each line and then make a request to a server which responds with an event RequestResponse and I then log the response.  the RequestResponse takes a second of so, and the way I have the code set up now it just flies through the CSV file and I get an output for each iteration but it is mostly the output I would expect for the first iteration with a little of the output of the second iteration.  I need to know how to make iteration wait until there has been a RequestResponse event before continuing on to the next iteration.  is this possible?

I have based this code largely in part on 
[NodeJs reading csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080413/nodejs-reading-csv-file)

but I am a little lost tbh with Node.js and with async.foreach.  any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your work on this will become a lot easier if you can use Promises and Node 7, which has `async` and `await` keywords. Then you can simply use a traditional `for` loop exactly like you are used to. https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly/

Comment: this is all command line on fedora box, so i can probably use anything and everything, i will give it a look

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you bite the bullet and take your time learning promises and `async/await`.  Then you can just use a regular for loop and await a web response promise.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is straight forward. You need to call the "callback" after the server return thats it.

```
async.eachSeries(data, function (line, callback) {
        SERVER.Request(line[0], line[1]);
        SERVER.on("RequestResponse", function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                SERVER.removeAllListeners("RequestResponse", callback)
        });

})
```

What is happening is that eachSeries is expecting callback AFTER you are down with the particular call.

Comment: i am more than certain i placed the callback in the event response function as well, but i will check it again thanks

Comment: i actually did do what you suggested and the code hangs on the second request and just times out or it spits out  if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");

Comment: Then there is an issue with the server.on call, is that an http library like request? https://github.com/request/request. Callback should definitely be in that spot, but perhaps the RequestResponse is not exactly what you need. Can you edit the question with the exact non-simplified code. The Error message suggests that .on is being called multiple times like, client receiving chunks of data maybe

Comment: well right the csv is about 100 lines long and i am running the request on each line and need to get the event for each request, before i start the next request and then wait for its event response before the next so on and so forth.  I guess what you are saying is that I should find another way?  idk.

Comment: also this isnt a typical request it is a call to the steam game coordinator with an event response

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, since server is a single emitter. We are registering multiple callback on same event. Need to use Server.removeAllListeners("ServerResponse") before making another request

Comment: I appreciate all your communique and help brother, but it stalls after the first iteration.  I will dive into the steam code tomorrow, and maybe there will be other answers