# How to read csv file in node js

Tags: node.js, csv, express, meanjs, fs

I am trying to read a csv file using node js.
Her is my code

```
fs.readFile(config.csvUploadPath, function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(data + 'my data')
});
```

CONSOLE:

```
ID
D11
D33
D55
```

Here I want to get the elements in the column ID and store those in an array. How can I do that? Can anyone suggest me help. Thanks.
My controller:

```
var partnersModel = new partners(params);
        fs.readFile(config.csvUploadPath, function read(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        dataArray = data.toString().split(/\r?\n/);
            dataArray.forEach(function(v,i){
                if(v !== 'DUI'){
                  partnersModel.dui.push(v);
                }
            });
        });
        partnersModel.save(function(error, response){
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080413/nodejs-reading-csv-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJs reading csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080413/nodejs-reading-csv-file)

Comment: Is this actually a CSV file, or just a file containing a list of IDs?  This would be pretty easy to parse without a library, but if you are parsing true CSV definitely use one!  My module of choice is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv

Comment: Hi.Bailsey ihave only one column name ID and want to store all the values of it in an array.

Comment: This is not really CSV then, it is just a file with data on each row.  You could use `data.split('\n')` [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split].  It would return an array like you desire.

Comment: partnersModel.save is being called before any of the file reading happens.  Use `async.waterfall` or something.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: you can try this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-grape

Answer (score 53):

Use a library, CSV has lots of gotchas.  I have come to enjoy the package `csv`.  It is located here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv .  Here is a very quick example using the async api.

```
const fs = require('fs')
var parse = require('csv-parse')
fs.readFile(inputPath, function (err, fileData) {
  parse(fileData, {columns: false, trim: true}, function(err, rows) {
    // Your CSV data is in an array of arrys passed to this callback as rows.
  })
})
```

Since your file does not have multiple values per row and contains no delimiters besides newline, it is only trivially CSV.  Maybe `String.prototype.split()` is for you?

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(inputPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);  //Be careful if you are in a \r\n world...
  // Your array contains ['ID', 'D11', ... ]
})
```

Comment: CSV files typically  have multiple values per row, so it returns an array of  arrays... one for each row.  For your example `rows= [ ['id'], ['D11'], ['D33'], ['D55'] ]`.  Note that the header was parsed too, and that to index one of the values you would need to use something like `rows[1][0]`.

Comment: There are options about header handling, and the library can help you stuff the values into objects for each row with properties matching the column names.  TFM is located here: http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/

Comment: But i am getting the error' data.split is not a function'

Comment: I thought `readFile` always passed a string as data, but apparently it only does if you specify an encoding.  The example has been updated!

Comment: i got it by this...  dataArray = data.toString().split(/\r?\n/);

Comment: In your example using 'csv-parse' I do not understand how you access the data in the end?

Comment: @newandlost The sample is from before promises were a big thing, so it uses callbacks. Basically there is an anonymous function defined at the innermost level that node-csv calls with your parsed rows in an array. If you are still working on this I would be glad to help with an async/await version :)

Answer (score 18):

I used a stream, `fs`, and `csv-parse` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37182426/2553191):

```
const parse = require('csv-parse')
const fs = require('fs') 

const data = []
fs.createReadStream(filename)
  .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ',' }))
  .on('data', (r) => {
    console.log(r);
    data.push(r);        
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Comment: How do I access the data in the array? for some reason (i think it because of the async nature of createReadStream) the array lentght equals 0, when I try to check it

Comment: parse is not defined.

Comment: @KylePennell You have to `const csv = require('csv-parse')` which imports the whole module and then use the parse method of that with `csv.parse(...`

Answer (score 0):

From [How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289296/3491991), use the jQuery-CSV library.

> Note: The library is designed to handle any CSV data that is RFC 4180 compliant, including all of the nasty edge cases that most 'simple' solutions overlook.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
$.csv = require('jquery-csv');

var sample = './path/to/data/sample.csv';
fs.readFile(sample, 'UTF-8', function(err, csv) {
  $.csv.toArrays(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
    for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]); //Will print every csv line as a newline
    }
  });
});
```

code snippet from `jquery-csv`'s examples [here](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/node-usage.js).