# Add Headers to CSV and Return Row with Matching String in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, csv, highland.js

I am trying to return a row value on a matching string.

I begin with a csv that doesn't have header details.  After loading the csv into memory, I think I need to first add headers and then convert the data to json, then loop through the data to find the correct object in the array.

I have used highland to create a read stream and output to objects.  However, the line break characters `\r` and `\r\n` are not getting parsed out and are injected into the value strings.

This approach also doesn't seem to parse the entire file, it is outputting 3 lines.

```
highland(fs.createReadStream('example.csv', 'utf8'))
  .map(line => line.split(','))
  .map(parts => ({
    a: parts[0],
    b: parts[1],
    c: parts[2]
}))
.each(x => console.log(x))
```

It would be nice to structure the CSV as JSON and then use the `.filter()` method to match the record.

Actual output of 1000+ line file

```
{ a: '', b: 'CD53110' }
{ a: '\nRD40115', b: 'CD40315' }
{ a: '', b: '63\r\nRE15468' }
{ a: '96798', b: '5\r\nRR60899' }
```

Example input snippet

```
,CD510,13
,T9069,65
RCM22,TC633,101
RC023,87693,16
M2024,T7636,109
```

Note: first few rows only contain 'b' and 'c' columns.

Comment: Convert the CSV into an array/object, adding the headers after is trivially easy.

Comment: What method would you use?

Comment: Loop through the created array/object, then create another array/object in the same format with updated key names.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Matthew What have you tried?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
`3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`

Comment: Yep. Sure thing.

Comment: Question was modeled on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080413/nodejs-reading-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the headers out as a string, set the csv to memory, and concatenate the two.

Then with the `csvtojson` module you can map the `csv` to `json` and use the native filter function to return the matching row.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csvtojson')

let headers = 'a,b,c\n'
let file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'example.csv', 'utf8')
let strToMatch = 'def123'

let c = headers + file

csv().fromString(c)
  .then((json) => {
    let arr = json.filter(el => el.a == strToMatch)
    res.json({
      a: arr[0]['a'],
      b: arr[0]['b'],
      c: arr[0]['c']
    })
})
```