# Reading a csv file async - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to create a function where I can pass file path and the read the file in async way. What I found out was that it supports `streams()`

```
const fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var async = require('async');

readCSVData = async (filePath): Promise<any> => {
    let csvString = '';
    var parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function (err, data) {
        async.eachSeries(data, function (line, callback) {
            csvString = csvString + line.join(',')+'\n';
            console.log(csvString) // I can see this value getting populated
        })
      });
      fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(parser);
}
```

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080413/nodejs-reading-csv-file). but I am new to node js so I am not getting how to use `await` to get the data once all lines are parsed.

```
const csvData = await this.util.readCSVData(path)
```

Comment: is there any promise base csv library is exist right now for node js older versions (i.e nodejs v4.2.0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30089770/3731501) provides legacy code that uses `async` *library*. Promise-based control flow with `async` doesn't need this library. Asynchronous processing with `async.eachSeries` doesn't serve a good purpose inside `csv-parse` callback because a callback waits for `data` to be filled with all collected data.

If reading all data into memory is not an issue, CSV stream can be converted to a promise:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const getStream = require('get-stream');
const parse = require('csv-parse');

readCSVData = async (filePath): Promise<any> => {
  const parseStream = parse({delimiter: ','});
  const data = await getStream.array(fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(parseStream));
  return data.map(line => line.join(',')).join('\n');
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than the other answer? Performance?

Comment: I can't say about better, but it processes data in chunks, this will waste less memory if a file is big. Also, `data` should preferably be processed in-place instead of  accumulating it into a single big array.

Answer (score 22):

My best workaround for this task is:

```
const csv = require('csvtojson')
const csvFilePath = 'data.csv'
const array = await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
```

Comment: This answer helped to fix the issue I was facing.