# Read a file one character at a time in node.js?

Tags: node.js, stream

Is there a way to read one symbol at a time in nodejs from file without storing the whole file in memory?
I found an answer for [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js)

I tried something like this but it doesn't help:

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream("walmart.dump", {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fd: null,
    bufferSize: 1,
});
stream.on('data', function(sym){
    console.log(sym);
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Readable stream has a [read()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size) method, where you can pass the length, in bytes, of every chunk to be read. For example:

```
var readable = fs.createReadStream("walmart.dump", {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fd: null,
});
readable.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read(1) /* here */)) {
    console.log(chunk); // chunk is one byte
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lower-level way to do it: [fs.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

using:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// open file for reading, returns file descriptor
const fd = fs.openSync('your-file.txt','r');

function readOneCharFromFile(position, cb){

        // only need to store one byte (one character)
        const b = new Buffer(1);

        fs.read(fd, b, 0, 1, position, function(err,bytesRead, buffer){
            console.log('data => ', String(buffer));
            cb(err,buffer);
        });

}
```

you will have to increment the position, as you read the file, but it will work.

here's a quick example of how to read a whole file, character by character

Just for fun I wrote this complete script to do it, just pass in a different file path, and it should work

```
const async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


function read(fd, position, cb) {

    let isByteRead = null;
    let ret = new Buffer(0);

    async.whilst(
        function () {
            return isByteRead !== false;
        },
        function (cb) {
            readOneCharFromFile(fd, position++, function (err, bytesRead, buffer) {

                if(err){
                    return cb(err);
                }

                isByteRead = !!bytesRead;
                if(isByteRead){
                    ret = Buffer.concat([ret,buffer]);
                }

                cb(null);
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            cb(err, ret);
        }
    );

}


function readOneCharFromFile(fd, position, cb) {

    // only need to store one byte (one character)
    const b = new Buffer(1);
    fs.read(fd, b, 0, 1, position, cb);

}


 /// use your own file here
const file = path.resolve(__dirname + '/fixtures/abc.txt');
const fd = fs.openSync(file, 'r');

// start reading at position 0, position will be incremented
read(fd, 0, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('data => ', String(data));
    }
    fs.closeSync(fd);
});
```

As you can see we increment the position integer every time we read the file. Hopefully the OS keeps the file in memory as we go. Using async.whilst() is OK, but I think for a more functional style it's better not to keep the state in the top of the function (ret and isByteRead). I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to implement this without using those stateful variables.

Comment: `fs.openSync` will read the whole file at once... this is the opposite of what OP wanted.

Comment: One character does not always equal one byte. Consider Chinese characters, for example.

Comment: No, the fs.openSync function in Node.js does not open the whole file at once. It is used to open a file and return a file descriptor synchronously. The file descriptor is a low-level representation of an open file, and it is typically used with other file system functions like fs.readSync or fs.writeSync to perform specific operations on the file.

Comment: Opening a file with fs.openSync does not read the entire file into memory. It simply provides a way to obtain a file descriptor that can be used for subsequent operations. If you need to read the contents of a file, you would use other functions like fs.readSync or fs.readFileSync, but keep in mind that these functions read a specified number of bytes or the entire file, depending on how you use them. It's still up to you to control the size of the data you read from the file.

Comment: @JohnDeighan you're correct that Chinese characters are typically encoded as 3 bytes per character. So we could rename the answer, read text 1-byte at a time instead of 1 character at a time