# How to read file character by character with Node.js

Tags: node.js, readline, fs

I know you can read line-by-line with `require('readline')`, is there a good way to read a file character by character? Perhaps just use readline and then split the line into characters?

I am trying to convert this code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const lines = String(fs.readFileSync(x));

for(const c of lines){
   // do what I wanna do with the c
}
```

looking to make this into something like:

```
fs.createReadStream().pipe(readCharByChar).on('char', c => {
    // do what I wanna do with the c
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file one character at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096691/read-a-file-one-character-at-a-time-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loop

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('filepath', 'utf-8');
for (const ch of data){
  console.log(ch
}
```

Using forEach

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('filepath', 'utf-8');
data.split('').forEach(ch => console.log(ch)
```

Comment: `readFileSync` will read the entire file and place the results in an array. It is not the same as streaming the contents of the file one character at a time