# Read an uploaded file line-by-line (FS.File, stored using cfs:gridfs)

Tags: javascript, meteor, gridfs

I have a Meteor app where I'd like to upload a text file then have the file parsed on the server. I'm using `cfs:gridfs` (with `cfs:standard-package`, of course) to store the files on the server.

Client code:

```
Template.uploadPathway.events({
  "submit #upload-pathway": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser form submit

    var pathwayFile = event.target.pathwayFile.files[0];

    UploadedFiles.insert(pathwayFile, function(error, fileObject) {
      // error handling removed for brevity
      Meteor.call("parseFile", fileObject._id);
    });
  }
});
```

Server code (in server folder, not Meteor.isServer):

```
Meteor.methods({
  parseFile: function (fileId) {
    var theFile = UploadedFiles.findOne({ _id: fileId });
    console.log(theFile);
    // how do I parse this file??
  }
});
```

The above code works beautifully, but I have no idea how to read the data inside the FS.File

Comment: you can use `theFile.createReadStream()` to read the file. Once you have that, you can search stack overflow for ideas on how to read a text file line by line given a stream, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js.

Comment: @ChristianFritz: The problem was that `theFile.createReadStream()` would crash because the file hadn't finished saving yet. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Dobbertin's](https://github.com/aldeed) answer to my question:

> First, note that when the `insert` callback fires on the client, the
>   file is probably not done uploading yet, and even if it’s been
>   uploaded, might not be done storing to the data store. So calling your
>   method in the `insert` callback isn’t a good way to do this.
>
> If you need to do it in a method, because you want to read the data
>   and send something back to the client, then you could set up an
>   `autorun` function where you wait for `fileObj.hasStored(storeName)`
>   to be `true`. Then you can call the method and stop the autorun
>   computation. ([link to hasStored
>   documentation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/blob/devel/packages/file/api.md#fsfilehasstoredstorename-optimisticanywhere))
>
> Try something like that and then see if your code works. Depending on
>   what exactly you are trying to do with the data, there may be some
>   better way to do it instead of the “data” event handler.
>
> If the client does not need to be involved, then a simpler way to
>   trigger your code after each file is stored is to use a "stored"
>   listener on the store:
>
> ```
> UploadedFileStore.on("stored", function (storeName, fileObject) {
>   if (storeName !== UploadedFileStore.name) return; // workaround for known bug
>
>   // your code
>
>   fileObject.createReadStream("uploaded_files")
>     .on('data', function (chunk) {
>       console.log("chunk: " + chunk);
>     });
> });
> ```