# Using readline, how to read one line at a time?

Tags: node.js

Here is the code:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import readline from 'readline';

let rl;

rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/allCountries.txt')
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    rl.pause();

    console.log('pause');

    // Do something that takes time with the line....
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('resume');

        rl.resume();
    }, 500);
});
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```js
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
pause
resume
```

but instead the output is:

```js
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
pause
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
resume
```

How do I force [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module to read one line, pause and wait until reading is resumed?

Comment: Does your `allCountries.txt` changes over time?

Comment: No. The assumption is that the file remains static while it is being read.

Comment: I am asking because if the file is static, I suggest seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js) instead of using `readline` module, since it is meant to be used with streams.

Comment: Ironically, the thread that you are referring (the selected answer) to recommends using `readline`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js/32599033#32599033

Comment: The thing is that according to the docs `pause` "doesn't immediately pause the stream of events. Several events may be emitted after calling pause, including line.". So I was hoping that one of suggestions in the question itself might be of use.