# How to do loop to write files from list in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to do loop to write files, I need to know how to load a file as cities.txt, this content inside looks like:

```
Los Angeles
San Francisco
St. Louis
New York
Philadelphia
Miami
Houston
Dallas
Kansas City
Memphis
...
```

This list includes new line, I'm looking a script to do loop, the output would be like this screenshot:

[image: loop list]

Also the space string needs to be replaced from " " to "-" to prevent error due to naming file rules.

Comment: You want to know how to load a series of txt files in Node.js and do something with their respective content. Did I get that right?

Comment: @JackZelig Yes but just one txt file which contains list of cities, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html), the core node module.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var lr = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('cities.txt')
});

lr.on('line', function (line) {
  var fileName = line.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
  fs.writeFileSync(fileName + ".json", '');
});
```

This SO thread is quite helpful: [Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-n)

Comment: It didn't write the files, it only shows list of cities in console.