# reading a file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to read a file using node.js

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile("details.txt",'utf8',function(err,data)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        response.write(data);
    });
```

there is a file alredy with some text in the same directory.

Error im getting is :

response.write(data);
               ^
ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Have you tried using "./details.txt" as the path?

Comment: @mcgraphix — Why should that make a difference?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `err` would be false but `data` undefined.

Comment: ./ refers to the working directory. Juat trying to ensure it is looking in the right place.

Comment: yes. still giving the same error.

Comment: i changed the code to this

var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile("./details.txt",'',function(err,data)
 {
  if(!err)
  { 
   return console.log(err);
  }

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
  response.write(data);
 });


now im getting a error in console "null" which is in the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: File order]

Above img shows my File order. Note: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA. You will have to find the file "details.txt" in your system.

```
//Instead of using hard coded path, use: the following code to get the path in Node.js
//var path = require('path');
//console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../details.txt'));

//require file system
var fs = require('fs');

//read file
fs.readFile("details.txt",'utf8',function(err,data){

  //if error, log error and return
  if(err) { return console.error('Error: ' + err); }


  //check if there is data in the file
  if(data) {

     //EDITED to include line break
    //write response
    //response.write('<div style="color:green">' + data + '</div>');

    //write response with <br>
    response.write('<div style="color:green">' + data.split('\n').join('<br>') + '</div>');

    //end the response
    response.end();


  //if no data on the file, do the following
  }else{
    //error variable
    var error = "Error: file is empty: " + data.length + " bytes.";

    //log error
    // console.error(error);

    //write response
    response.write('<div style="color:red">' + error + '</div>');

    //end response
    response.end();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes!!! It's worked. Thanks so much!!!!

Any tips of retrieving the output line by line ? at the moment it is displaying all the details in one line.

Comment: @CJM You can use readLine function instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/3359432

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code for write data to. data.split('\n').join('<br>')

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path to 'details.txt' (i.e. '/etc/hosts'). And, send it to console.log just to confirm it works.

Comment: it is in the home directory where all the other files are server.js, router.js

Comment: I can write into the file but only when im reading it gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile("details.txt",'utf8',function(err,data)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
```

the error is

```
response.write(data)
```