# How to read a file line by line 1 line at a time

Tags: node.js

Not a duplicate of [Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js).

All the examples in the other thread answer how to read a file line-by-line. But none of them focus on how to read a file line-by-line **one-line-at-a-time**.

To illustrate, I have adapted code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/368691) in the other thread:

```
let index = 0;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, './countries.txt'))
});

rl.on('line', () => {
    console.log('line', ++index);

    rl.pause();
});
```

Depending on the speed of the machine executing the code, the output of running this program will be something along the lines of:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
...
line 564
line 565
line 566
line 567
```

How to read a file line-by-line **one-line-at-a-time**?

To emphasize the intention of using `rl.pause` in the example: I need to get 1 line from a file and halt further reading of the file until I explicitly request the second line.

Comment: Not an answer, but I found that https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader#usage abstracts the interface to read a file line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really understand why you use readline interface to read a file.

I suggest you to use [split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split), such as

```
  var splitstream = fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(split())
  splitstream
    .on('data', function (line) {
      //each chunk now is a seperate line!
      splitstream.pause();
      setTimeout(function (){ splitstream.resume() }, 500);
    })
```

you will definitely get one line at a time.

** edited for the comment.

Comment: I need to get a line from a file and stop further processing until I explicitly ask for a new line.

Comment: You pause and resume the stream if you need to.

Comment: readline is indeed to read a stream line-by-line according to the doc.... But it s mostly build to deal with stdin, when the user types in something and press [enter]. see https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read file line by line and process a line before reading the next line.

```
var fs=require('fs');
var readable = fs.createReadStream("data.txt", {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  fd: null
});
var lines=[];//this is array not a string!!!
readable.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk,tmp='';
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read(1))) {
    if(chunk==='\n'){
      tmp='';
      lines.push(tmp);
    //  here tmp is containing a line you can process it right here.
    //  As i am just pushing the line in the array lines.
    //  use async if you are processing it asynchronously.
    }else
      tmp+=chunk;
  }
});
readable.on('end',function(){
  var i=0,len=lines.length;
  while(i<len)
    console.log(lines[i++]);
});
```