# Searching text file with readline node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

Please consider below code. What I want to do is to pick name from `names.txt` in `createStream` function one by one and from there call `FileSearch` function with `nameToSearch` as parameter and search `list.txt` line by line. So one name and search `list.txt` line by line, another name and search `list.txt` line by line and so on...

`list.txt` ,is a large file. If finds a match, output the search string and line number. I thought it'll out put one name and line numbers and then move on to second name and so on but it is

1. Skipping rows. I searched some names manually and corresponding line numbers are not there in output)
2. Mixing names. I can see names in the initial part of the output and then somewhere else in the output.

Code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var readline = require('readline');

var nameToSearch

var createStream = function (){
var lineNumber=0;
var ended = false;
var rlName = readline.createInterface({
      input : fs.createReadStream('./names.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
      })
rlName.on('line',function(lineInNameFile){
     ++lineNumber;
      nameToSearch=lowercase(lineInNameFile);
     FileSearch(nameToSearch);
     })
}


var lowercase=function(str){
     return String(str).toLowerCase();
}

var  FileSearch = function (searchString){
var listlineNumber=0;
var rlList = readline.createInterface({   
      input : fs.createReadStream('./list-2.txt'),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
})
rlList.on('line',function(lineInListFile){
     ++listlineNumber;
     if (lineInListFile===searchString){
         console.log( searchString+ ":" + listlineNumber);
     } 

})

} 

var runSearch = createStream();
exports.createStream = createStream;
```

`names.txt` looks like this

```
OLIVER
CHARLOTTE
LIAM
AMELIA
.
.
```

and `list.txt` looks like this, basically one word per line in both files

```
a
aah
aahed
aahing
aback
abacus
abacuses
abaft
abalone
abalones
.
.
```

My out put on console is something like this

```
grayson:2322
emmett:3756
emmett:6399
lily:3739
lily:6340
.
.
```

Am I not using `readline` module correctly?

**EDIT:**  upon looking into more and searching found that it might have to do something with reading last line. Its not reading the last line of `list.txt`. I am not sure why

Comment: Just want to verify that you're expecting `list-2.txt` not `list.txt` as seen here: `input : fs.createReadStream('./list-2.txt'),`

Comment: `list-2.txt` was a typo, the issue remains as is. But I've manage to solve it. I'll post answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to resolve the issue by using line-by-line module and now the output is exact as expected. heres the code

```
var nameToSearch

//Function to retrieve names

var createStream = function (){

var lineNumber=0;
var nameLine = require('line-by-line')
lrName = new nameLine('./names.txt');
//lrName = new nameLine('./names-testFile.txt');

var ended = false;

 lrName.on('line', function (lineInNameFile) {
    ++lineNumber;
    nameToSearch=lowercase(lineInNameFile);
    FileSearch(nameToSearch);
 });     


}


var lowercase=function(str){
     return String(str).toLowerCase();
}

 //Function to search in list file

var  FileSearch = function (searchString){

    var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
    lr = new LineByLineReader('./list.txt');
    //lr = new LineByLineReader('./list-testFile.txt');
    var listlineNumber=0
    var arr = []

    lr.on('line', function (lineInListFile) {
        ++listlineNumber;
        if (lineInListFile===searchString){
            arr.push(listlineNumber);

        } 
     });

     lr.on('end', function () {
            console.log( searchString+ ":" + arr);
     });

} 

var runSearch = createStream();

exports.createStream = createStream;
```