# Javascript stopping an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, events

Is it possible at all to stop an event and force it to end?

```
string rows // Correctly formatted csv string.

csv
  .fromString(rows, { headers: false })
  .on('data', (data) => {
    if (condition) {
       // force to end.
    }
  }
  .on('end', () => cb(units));
```

I am therefore looking to break out of the csv file early.

Comment: What csv library are you using?

Comment: Could be https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson

Comment: If the csv library does not handle validation you need, then you can [read the file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42232026/searching-text-file-with-readline-node-js/42301177#42301177) and process it as you see fit. I think the same applies to a user-provided string.

Comment: But if the question is about ending some execution context abruptly, then `return` or even `throw` may be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using [node-csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson).

I think you can stop emitting data event like this:

```js
const converter = csv.fromString(rows, { headers: false })
converter.on('data', (data) => {
  if (condition) {
    converter.removeAllListeners('data');// where 'data' is the name of the event. If called without any arguments, all listeners added to csv converter will be removed
  }
}
```

Source: [this thread on Github](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/127).

Comment: Did you try it? I tried the above solution, its not working. Also the above off method is not mentioned in the documentation

Comment: Actually, I didn't test, I just read this [thread](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/issues/127). But I read too quickly, you apparently have to use `removeAllListeners` rather than `off`.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
const task = csv.fromString(rows, { headers: false })
task.on('data', (data) => {
  if (condition) {
    task.on('end', () => cb(units));
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt do that. The 'end' callback should exist prior to calling 'data'.