# Read node-serialport stream line by line

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node-serialport

### Setup

The [official documentation has a part](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#serialportparsers--object) on how to read a [node-serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) stream line by line.

I tried the example code:

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1');
var parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);
parser.on('data', console.log);
port.write('ROBOT PLEASE RESPOND\n');
```

I quickly realised that `SerialPort.parsers.Readline` should be `SerialPort.parsers.readline` but even this way I still get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: dest.on is not a function

### Problem

Later I realised this functionality is only available since 5.0.0 which is in beta (as of early 2017). I have 4.0.7. So how can I read the stream line by line below version 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Just [read it like a regular stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32599033/1494454):

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var createInterface = require('readline').createInterface;

var port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty-usbserial1');

var lineReader = createInterface({
  input: port
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log(line);
});

port.write('ROBOT PLEASE RESPOND\n');
```

### Explanation

Since node-serialport's prototype is [`Stream`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), surprisingly you can read it like a regular `Stream` and the length of this solution is about the same as the one give in the documentation.